# KendoUI: why Dates in categoryAxis are shuffled?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm using KendoUI DataViz Chart to show the statistical data and having dates coming from JSON datasource and are being set as categoryAxis, but they get shuffled automatically, i.e; somehow the middle date is showing as the first field and vice versa. Please find the attached screenshot for detail. 
I don'nt konw why is it happening, Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that you hit the problem with the [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers) in Chrome :). This problem is fixed with the Q2 2012 SP1 release of the Kendo UI.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Kendo UI Charts are looking for a unix time stamp. Try formatting a couple of your values as a time stamp and then using a template to format the date like this:

```
categoryAxis: {
    labels: {
        template: "#= formatDate(value) #"
    }
}
```

The formatDate will be a function that you define that can produce the string you want displayed in the axis.

I think this approach will allow kendo to order your dates correctly AND give you the format you are looking for.