# d3v2 - Dom sorting does not work in Safari

Tags: sorting, safari, d3.js

I'm having some trouble using the dom sorting in Safari, it basically does not move the dom items.
The ordering works in Chrome and Firefox, my only issue is on Safari.
This is the code i am using:

```
var hovered = d3.select(this)[0][0]['__data__']['properties']['name'];
g.selectAll("path").sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.properties.name == hovered ? 1 : 0);;
});
```

I am using this because later in the code i am doing some scaling on the hovered path, and if its not last in the dom tree it appears behind the paths that are after it.

Any help on the matter would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven’t implemented a valid comparator for [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). A comparator needs to return a number less than zero if *a* should be before *b*, a number greater than zero if *a* should be after *b*, and zero if you don’t care about the relative order of *a* and *b*.

If you want to move the hovered name to the front, you need something like this:

```
function order(a, b) {
  return (a.properties.name == hovered) - (b.properties.name == hovered);
}
```

The reason the ordering works in Safari and Firefox is that they use [stable sorting algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers), preserving the order when your comparator returns 0. However, this behavior is not guaranteed by the ECMAScript standard, so you should implement a proper comparator instead of relying on this browser-specific behavior. (If you really need stable sort, you can build that into your comparator, but then you need to cache the previous order.)

All that said, it’s faster to move a specific node to the front on hover, rather than sorting all the elements:

```
path.on("mouseover", function() {
  this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
});
```

You can even define a [moveToFront](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/eUEJWSSWDRY/EMmufH2KP8MJ) method if you find yourself doing this often.