# Random values based on array inside a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have 4 different classes that need to be added to a `div` inside a `ng-repeat`.

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <span class="color-RANDOM-VALUE">{{post.title}}</span>
</li>
```

Once I have the loop running, it should look like:

```
<li>
    <span class="color-blue">Title</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="color-yellow">Title</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="color-purple">Title</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="color-red">Title</span>
</li>
```

Any suggestions on the best way to do that?

Comment: What is the current output you are getting from your ng-repeat?

Comment: So do you need a random number in a range, like 1-4 to pick a random color?  If so, look at this for getting a random number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a built in directive called ng-class.  You can have your scope return random classes for the element to use as follows:

```html
<li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <span ng-class="getRandomColorClass()">{{post.title}}</span>
</li>
```

```js
var colorArray = [ 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow', 'grey' ];

$scope.getRandomColorClass = new function() {
  return 'color-' + colorArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * colorArray.length))];
};
```

Comment: For some reason it's saying that getRandomColorClass() function is not defined.

Comment: The code snippet I wrote is supposed to be in your controller.

Comment: This wont work and throw a angular error [$rootScope:infdig]. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586369/random-orderby-in-angularjs-1-2-returns-infdig-errors