# reorder list randomly in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat as following :

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="o in villes | limitTo:5"><a href="#">{{o.nomVille}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to reorder the `villes` list randomly before I limit it to `5`, so every time I open my page I get 5 different `villes` each time.

is there a filter in angularjs who can do that for me ?

## edit :

I created a costum filter to randomize that list as following :

```
.filter('random', function() {
  return function(val) {
    let shuffle = (a) => {
      let r = [];
      while (arr.length)
        r.push(
          arr.splice( (Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)) , 1)[0]
        );

      return shuffle(val);
    }
  };
});
```

and in ng-repeat I did this :

```
<li ng-repeat="o in villes | random | limitTo:5"><a href="#">{{o.nomVille}}</a></li>
```

but I cant no longer see anything in my page.

this is the example on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/z10wwhcv/

Comment: you need a shuffle array function

Comment: pass your array through a [function like this](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/1ceurr64/) in the controller

Comment: @maioman check my edit please

Comment: I think the filter you made doesn't actually call the `shuffle` function on anything?

Comment: @Mike it does in  return `shuffle(val);`

Comment: Looks to me like that line is part of the shuffle function itself

Comment: @Mike https://jsfiddle.net/z10wwhcv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I created :

```
shufflemodule.filter('shuffle', function() {
    var shuffledArr = [],
        shuffledLength = 0;
    return function(arr) {
        var o = arr.slice(0, arr.length);
        if (shuffledLength == arr.length) return shuffledArr;
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        shuffledArr = o;
        shuffledLength = o.length;
        return o;
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aimad_majdou/6mngvo38/

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to build a custom filter function that randomizes the order and then apply the filters in the correct order (random before limit).

Have a look at this for details:

[Using AngularJS how could I randomize the order of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101989/using-angularjs-how-could-i-randomize-the-order-of-a-collection)

Comment: how can I define some filter using that random function ? since I want to use it for multiple controllers ?

Comment: In that case have a look at actually defining it as a filter (as opposed to a controller function which it is now).

The angular doc for custom filters can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: If you look at the JS console you'll probably find that one of your dependencies is missing. If that happens angular doesn't render the rest of the page.

Comment: I dont think so since I dont get anything in console

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order to change each time you load the page you can't do it as a filter as that will presumably change on each digest cycle. You need to store `villes` on the scope somewhere and generate it in a random order when the page loads, e.g. in your controller function for that page.

Answer (score 0):

use the filter in the controller (which is also a best practice performance boost):

```
$scope.shuffled = $filter('random',$scope.villes)
```

you'll need to inject the service in the controller

---

this is what your filter should look like ( not tested but should work ):

```
 .filter('random', function() {
          return function(a) {

              var r = [];
              while (a.length)
                r.push(
                  a.splice((Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)), 1)[0]
                );
              return r;
          }
        }
```

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU your fiddle wasn't working principally because you had some syntax errors; here's the debugged version using filter inside controller - https://jsfiddle.net/maio/z10wwhcv/1/