# How to make specific option of select list show in the first row using vueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here bellow the code to loop the elements of `teamLeaderOfWithDescendants`

```
<option :value="item.user_id" v-for="item in teamLeaderOfWithDescendants">
   {{item.user_full_name}}
</option>
```

How to put the row where the `item.user_id` === `currentUserId` in the first position ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript move an item of an array to the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921683/javascript-move-an-item-of-an-array-to-the-front)

Comment: Where is the value of `currentUserId` coming from?

Comment: `currentUserId` is a variable which presents the current user Id (Auth)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks I found it ! `:selected="currentUserId === item.user_id"`

```
<option
:selected="currentUserId === item.user_id"
:value="item.user_id" 
v-for="item in teamLeaderOfWithDescendants">
{{item.user_full_name}}
</option>
```