# Using Javascript .sort() on an array to put all the zeros at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array so that all the zeros are at the end. However, I don't want the list to be numerically sorted, all the numbers  above zero should stay in the same order. Here's what I've got so far:

```
function placeZerosAtEnd(arr) {
    return arr.sort(compareForSort);
}
function compareForSort(first, second) {
    return first == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
placeZerosAtEnd([9,0,9,1,0,2,0,1,1,0,3,0,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0]);
```

This should return [9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], but actually returns [3,9,9,1,9,2,9,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. The zeros are correct, but the other numbers are in a strange order. What is going on here?

http://jsfiddle.net/v67fx4zk/

Comment: i guess its because of quicksort ("divide and conquer") so its a sort algorithms behavior.

Comment: You could do `xs.filter(isntZero).concat(xs.filter(isZero))`

Comment: I get the expected result with your fiddle. Did you try also handling the case where `second` is `0` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other have said, using .sort() was wrong in this instance. This is the code I used in the end, as suggested by elclanrs in the comments below my initial post.

```
function placeZerosAtEnd(arr) {
    return arr.filter(isntZero).concat(arr.filter(isZero));
}
function isntZero(element) {
    return element > 0;
}
function isZero(element) {
    return element == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The trivial solution with `sort`: "bubble down" zeros against non-zeros:

```
[9,0,9,1,0,2,0,1,1,0,3,0,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0].sort((a, b) => {
  if (a !== 0 && b === 0) return -1;
  if (a === 0 && b !== 0) return 1;
  return 0;
})

// [9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can accomplish this with the `sort` function.  Depending on the sort method the browser uses (quicksort, merge sort, etc.), the `sort` function works by swapping items into place.  So there's no telling where the non-zeroes will end up ... your algorithm simply ensures that they'll appear before the 0s.

Here's a function that will accomplish what you're trying:

```
function placeZerosAtEnd(arr) {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    if(arr[i]===0) arr.splice(arr.length-1, 0, arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this some way too

```js
let listSort = [9, 0, 9, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    isntZero = [],
    isZero = []

for (let i = 0; i < listSort.length; i++) {
  if (listSort[i] == 0)
    isZero.push(listSort[i])
  else
    isntZero.push(listSort[i])
}

let output = isntZero.concat(isZero)

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `sort` function is doing exactly what it's meant to.

You're expecting a `stable sort`, but a stable sort is not guaranteed by the javascript sort algorithm.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers) for a discussion on stable sorting in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arr.sort to solve this problem

reference:
[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
   function placeZerosAtEnd(arr) {

     arr.sort(function(key1,key2) {

      if (key1 == 0 ) return 1;
      return -1;
    });    
    return arr;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
arr.sort((a,b) => a - b).reverse()
```

Comment: Why not just do `b - a` and so remove the need for the `.reverse()`?