# separate positive and negative numbers in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to separate positive and negative numbers in an array using Javascript. But the code Iam trying to use is not working. Jere is the code I was trying to use which I got from [Separate negative and positive numbers in array with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036791/separate-negative-and-positive-numbers-in-array-with-javascript)

```
var t = [-1,-2,-3,5,6,1]
var positiveArr = [];
var negativeArr = [];
t.forEach(function(item){
if(item<0){
negativeArr.push(item);
}
else{
positiveArr.push(item)
})
console.log(positiveArr) // should output [5, 6, 1]
console.log(negativeArr) // should output [-1, -2, -3]
```

Comment: Just add `}` after `positiveArr.push(item)`

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."*

Comment: Better use `for (const item of t) { … }` for the loop so that you don't get confused by the closing `})` of `forEach`

Comment: Thanks Mr  T.J. Crowder , it worked ....I didnt know it was a typo , thanks anyway

Comment: Bergi Thanks I will try that too

Comment: @felix: Provided your target environment supports `for-of`, which is relatively new. (Or you're transpiling.) Regarding the `}`: If you indent and format your code in a consistent, readable fashion, this sort of thing will be really obvious and so hard to accidentally leave out, and easy to fix when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a closing bracket `}` in your conditional:

```js
var t = [-1, -2, -3, 5, 6, 1];

var positiveArr = [];
var negativeArr = [];

t.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item < 0) {
    negativeArr.push(item);
  } else {
    positiveArr.push(item)
  }
});

console.log(positiveArr) // should output [5, 6, 1]
console.log(negativeArr)
```

Comment: Typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future questions don't need answers, just close votes and comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = [-1,-2,-3,5,6,1];

var positiveArr = t.filter((elem) => elem > 0);
var negativeArr = t.filter((elem) => elem < 0);
```

Comment: And if `elem` is 0? :-)

Comment: 0 is not neither positive nor negative. Just a zero ;-)

Comment: no problem. Please remeber to mark your question as answered

Comment: okay thank you let me do that now , thank you so much again you are so helpful

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.