# d3.js custom colors weird behavior - gradient problems

Tags: d3.js

I have a question about the strange behavior of d3.js coloring. I want to create gradient in a pie chart and I used 2 solutions:

```
var data = 
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,       
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];


    var length = 100;
    var color = d3.scale.linear().domain([1,length])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl)
    .range([d3.rgb("#5C97C1"), d3.rgb('#FFC357')]);

// var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
//   .domain(data)
//   .range(
// ["#5C97C1", "#6199BE", "#639ABC", "#689CB9", "#6C9EB6", "#6F9FB4", "#73A1B1", "#78A3AD", "#7BA5AA", "#81A7A6",
//  "#84A8A4", "#88AAA1", "#8BAC9F", "#8FAD9C", "#93AF99", "#97B196", "#9BB393", "#9FB491", "#A2B68E", "#A8B88A", 
//  "#ABBA88", "#AFBC85", "#B2BD82", "#B7BF7F", "#BAC07D", "#BFC379", "#C3C476", "#C7C674", "#CAC871", "#CEC96E", 
//  "#D3CB6B", "#D1CB6C", "#D7CD68", "#DBCF65", "#DDCE64", "#DECE64", "#DFCE63", "#E0CD63", "#E1CD62", "#E3CC62", 
//  "#E3CC61", "#E5CC61", "#E6CB60", "#E7CB60", "#E8CB5F", "#E9CA5F", "#EACA5F", "#EBCA5E", "#ECC95E", "#EEC95D", 
//  "#EFC85D", "#F0C85C", "#F1C85C", "#F2C75B", "#F3C75B", "#F4C75A", "#F5C65A", "#F6C65A", "#F8C559", "#F9C559", 
//  "#FAC558", "#FBC458", "#FCC457", "#FDC457", "#FEC356", "#FEC256", "#FDBF57", "#FBBC58", "#FAB959", "#F9B759", 
//  "#F8B45A", "#F6B05C", "#F5AD5C", "#F3AA5D", "#F2A85E", "#F0A55F", "#EFA260", "#ED9E61", "#EC9C61", "#EB9962", 
//  "#EA9763", "#E79264", "#E69065", "#E58D66", "#E48B66", "#E38867", "#E18568", "#DF8169", "#DE7E6A", "#DC7B6B", 
//  "#DD7C6B", "#DB796C", "#D9756D", "#D8736D", "#D7706E", "#D56D6F", "#D46B70", "#D36871", "#D06272", "#CF6173"]);
```

Or full version here http://codepen.io/Balzzac/pen/EZGwGy?editors=1000

And I get weird behavior in the first slice and the 50th of 100 in both cases. I want to understand why and how to fix it?

[image] [image]

Comment: Even stranger, this looks to be an issue only in chrome (at least on mac).  Safari and Firefox render properly

Comment: I can confirm that Chrome on Ubuntu has this rendering issue, whereas Firefox does not. Strange. Maybe worth filing a bug report on the relevant d3 github page. Although note that you are using v3, whereas d3 is now v4, with some significant changes.

Comment: Can also confirm that the same issue appears when using d3 4.0, but again only on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging, here's what I've found.

The issue is primarily to do with the fact that the call to `pie(data)` does not return data in order of ascending angle. This is not an issue when you want to have your bar chart ordered largest-smallest, but in your case this is causing problems.

You can see this for yourself when you call `d3.layout.pie()(data)` in the console - the values are *almost* sorted, but with a few exceptions.

In D3 v3.0, the solution is to call `.sort(null)` when setting up your pie chart:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);
```

If you are using D3 v4.0 (which you should!), the solution is to call `.sortValue(null)`:

```
var pie = d3.pie().sortValues(null);
```

As an aside, the relevant changes to convert to D3 4.0 are:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

....

var color = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1,length])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl)
    .range([d3.rgb("#5C97C1"), d3.rgb('#FFC357')]);

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.pie().sortValues(null);

....
```

In relation to the difference between browsers, I have a suspicion it is related to [different sort implementations between browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers), but not 100% sure on this.

Comment: Still in Chrome doesn't work properly, but thanks for suggestions!

Comment: removed scale from colors - seems working properly now.