# How can I ensure a stable array.sort() order, javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

How can I ensure a stable .sort() order across all browsers? JavaScript

I have an array of objects, eg

```
[{
 thing: 'walker',
 value: 1
},
{
 thing: 'texas',
 value: 2
},
{
 thing: 'ranger',
 value: 2
}]
```

When sorting the array I sort them alternating asc/desc using:

```
 _sortNumber (key, dir) {
    return function(a, b) {
      if (dir) {
        // sort descending
        return b[key] - a[key];
      }
      else {
        // sort ascending
        return a[key] - b[key];
      }
    }
  };
```

`array.sort(this._sortNumber('value', Boolean));`

However, the order of `texas` and `ranger` seem to randomly change. I believe due to the fact that they are the same number, however, I would like it to be consistent.

How can I ensure consistency; or sort on a secondary value (eg `thing` alphabetically), in order to ensure I always get the same sort result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.sort Sorting Stability in Different Browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers)

Comment: You may want to check out [Tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/), it can multiple-sort : `tinysort(array,'value','thing')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, like [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and other sort implementations:

> The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

To maintain a stable sort, you could use a unique value, like an index as last sort value in the chain of sorting criteria, like

```
function asc(key) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return a[key] - b[key] || a.id - b.id;
    };
}

array.sort(asc('value'));
```

Comment: Did you mean `b[key]` instead of `b.key`?

Comment: I like the simplicity of this!

Comment: I just stumbled across this. Maybe interesting to mention: The linked page [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) now shows that sort is stable for all browsers except IE for several versions..

Answer (score 3):

Since you are writing your own sorting function anyway, you can just define what the logic should be when the values are equal.

```
_sortNumber (key, dir) {
    return function(a, b) {
      if (dir) {
        // sort descending
        if( a[key] !== b[key])
        {
          return b[key] - a[key];
        } else { //They are same.. sort by something else
          if (a.thing < b.thing){
            return 1;
          }else if (a.thing > b.thing){
            return  -1;
          }else{
            return 0;
          }
      }
      else {
        // sort ascending
        if( a[key] !== b[key])
        {
          return a[key] - b[key];
        } else {
          if (a.thing < b.thing){
            return -1;
          }else if (a.thing > b.thing){
            return  1;
          }else{
            return 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: The `thing` values are strings, so subtracting them doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's still not returning the positive/negative/zero indicators it's supposed to return.

Comment: There is [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort not only by `value` but also by `thing`

see this post: [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

If you use Excel and you've ever set the criteria for sort, you've seen how they give you the first, second, third, etc, fields to sort by.  That's what you need to do.  Set the first field as `value` and the second field as `thing`

The post I shared gives the code to do that.