# Javascript sort() using the arguments as property selectors for comparison produces weird results on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting

I've got an array of strings called `countKeys` which contains values that correspond to the keys of an object which in turn contains an integer.

I'm trying to sort the array with keys (`countKeys`) in accordance to their key value in the object (`count`).

Array with (string )keys:

```
var countKeys = ["0","6","8","10","12","13","14","17","18","19","22","27","30","35","39","48","50","51","55","58","61","66","76","88","94","107","108","109"];
```

Object with integer values that I'm trying to compare:

`var count = {"0":5,"6":1,"8":3,"10":3,"12":2,"13":3,"14":3,"17":3,"18":2,"19":2,"22":2,"27":1,"30":1,"35":1,"39":1,"48":1,"50":1,"51":2,"55":2,"58":2,"61":1,"66":1,"76":2,"88":1,"94":1,"107":1,"108":1,"109":1};`

I'm using the following sort function:

```
countKeys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return count[b] - count[a];
});
```

I'm expecting the following result for countKeys:

`["0","8","10","13","14","17","12","18","19","22","51","55","58","76","6","27","30","35","39","48","50","61","66","88","94","107","108","109"]`

On Firefox and IE, this works, on Chrome however, I'm getting unexpected results:

`["0","10","13","14","17","8","76","12","19","22","51","55","58","18","6","48","50","109","27","30","61","66","35","88","94","107","108","39"]`

How do I get the same result on Chrome as I'm getting on other browsers?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vvb3hvq5/3/)**

Comment: Your sort function doesn't specify that if the values are equal, it should use the array index as a secondary sort.  [JS sorts are not stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/array-sort-sorting-stability-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort by two properties:

1. The values in `count` (numerically)
2. The keys in `count` (numerically)

You currently only sort by value, but since each browser has a different sorting stability (i.e. whether or not to swap around *equal* elements), you’ll get different results. Sort by both properties like this:

```
countKeys.sort(function(a, b) {
  return count[b] - count[a] || b - a;
});
```

This way, if `count[b] - count[a]` is `0` (i.e. the values are equal), it proceeds to compare `a` and `b` (i.e. the keys) directly.