# sort a list of lists by how many values each list has

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

ok, this might have an answer but I'm not sure how to word it to find it.
I have a list of lists.

```
var listOLists = [['q','w','e'],['a'],['z','x']];
```

is there a way to sort it by length of lists, so I get a result

```
output.table(listOLists.specialLenghtsort());
    'a'
    'z','x'
    'q','w','e'
```

Comment: `listOLists.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use array sort method with a custom compare function.

```
listOLists.sort((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1)
```

If you want the order of same length item to be preserved  you need to do the following,

```
listOLists.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
```

Thanks to Patrick for pointing that out. For reference you can follow this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026281/what-is-the-stability-of-the-array-sort-method-in-different-browsers/3027715#3027715) link.

Comment: That's not a stable algorithm. That will likely swap any elements with equal lengths rather than preserving their initial relative ordering.

Comment: I have tried that, it is actually preserving relative ordering for an equal length.

Comment: [Are you sure about that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTXwk.png)

Comment: @Patrick True, but the question doesn't seem to require a stable algorithm.

Comment: In Firefox it is actually preserving the order. But after I in chrome, it breaks the order. Interesting. Thanks @PatrickRoberts for pointing that out.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon actually it is. Starting in ECMAScript 2019, the builtin `sort()` method is required by the specification to implement a stable sort algorithm (since before 2019, most engines already did except V8, which only [adopted a stable algorithm in 2018](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort)). So yes, as long as the callback returns `0` for two comparatively equal elements, the specification requires the builtin method to preserve their relative ordering as of 2019.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon read the paragraph about ECMAScript 2019 in the [introduction section](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-intro).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027715/1541563)