# javascript - Create Simple Dynamic Array

Tags: javascript

What's the most efficient way to create this simple array dynamically.

```
var arr = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
```

Let's say we can get the number 10 from a variable

```
var mynumber = 10;
```

Comment: Tail recursion would be fancier.

Comment: @joshp well he did say "most efficient" so i would go with a for-loop :P

Comment: do you really want those numbers to be stored as strings ?

Comment: Well I don't know if the js environment optimizes tail recursion. They would be equivalent then. I was mainly considering the fashion aspect.

Comment: How funny that somebody takes the time to reply but without being constructive

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=1; i<=mynumber; i++) {
   arr.push(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: it is not very healthy to expand the array on every loop, this is almost inevitable is most of the time, but this time we know the length. (see my ans for more info)

Answer (score 29):

With [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), this can be achieved concisely in a single expression using the `Array.from` method like so:

```
Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, idx) => `${++idx}`)
```

The first argument to `from` is an array like object that provides a length property. The second argument is a map function that allows us to replace the default `undefined` values with their adjusted index values as you requested. Checkout the specification [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from)

Comment: one thing to mention: you can use any variable name instead of '_', the first property of the map function represents the current value of the Arrays element ( arr[idx] ). in this example it is always 'undefined'

Answer (score 18):

> **Update:** micro-optimizations like this one are just not worth it, engines are so smart these days that I would advice in the 2020 to simply just go with `var arr = [];`.

Here is how I would do it:

```
var mynumber = 10;
var arr = new Array(mynumber);

for (var i = 0; i < mynumber; i++) {
    arr[i] = (i + 1).toString();
}
```

My answer is pretty much the same of everyone, but note that I did something different:

- It is better if you specify the array length and
  don't force it to expand every time

So I created the array with `new Array(mynumber);`

Comment: Why is it bad/not recommended to expand the array on every iteration? Does it affect the memory allocation or the time taken to store the value? Can you please elaborate on the drawbacks?

Comment: @YashKalwani basically work like copy and paste. if we haven't allocated a fixed size in memory there might be a new item placed near the last previous index. so compilers will instruct OS to copy this to another location and then insert it.

Answer (score 11):

This answer is about "how to dynamically create an array **without loop**".

Literal operator `[]` doesn't allow us to create dynamically, so let's look into `Array`, it's constructor and it's methods.

In ES2015 Array has method `.from()`, which easily allows us to create dynamic Array:

```
Array.from({length: 10}) // -> [undefined, undefined, undefined, ... ]
```

When Array's constructor receives number as first parameter, it creates an Array with size of that number, but it is not iterable, so we cannot use `.map()`, `.filter()` etc. :

```
new Array(10) // -> [empty × 10]
```

But if we'll pass more than one parameter we will receive array from all parameters:

```
new Array(1,2,3) // -> [1,2,3]
```

If we would use ES2015 we can use spread operator which will spread empty Array inside another Array, so we will get iterable Array :

```
[...new Array(10)]  // -> [undefined, undefined, undefined, ...]
```

But if we don't use ES2015 and don't have polyfills, there is also a way to create dynamic Array without loop in ES5. If we'll think about `.apply()` method: it spreads second argument array to params. So calling apply on Array's constructor will do the thing:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(10))  // -> [undefined, undefined, undefined, ...]
```

After we have dynamic iterable Array, we can use map to assign dynamic values:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(function(el, i) {return ++i + ""})

// ["1","2","3", ...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you just want to construct an array that contains the string versions of the integer values.  A simple approach:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= mynumber; i++) arr.push(""+i);
```

For a more interesting version you could do a generator...

```
function tail(i, maxval) {
    return [i].concat(i < maxval ? tail(i+1, maxval) : []);
}

var arr = tail(1, mynumber);
```

Comment: It would be faster if mynumber was local inside the tail function.

Comment: True - though I was thinking at one point about the python range(START, STOP, STRIDE) function.

Answer (score 3):

Since none of previous answers provide solution with `repeat` Here you go:
To generate dynamic array of ten numbers with `repeat`:

```js
[...'x'.repeat(10).split('').keys()]
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

To get what you want:

> `var arr = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];`

Just add one to all of elements keys *(since array are zero-based)* and convert numbers to string by *string literals* or `.toString()` or even just add empty space to number `''+x`.

```js
let mynumber = 10;

const keys = [...'x'.repeat(mynumber).split('').keys()]
const arr = keys.map(x=>`${x+1}`);
//['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [];
while(mynumber--) {
    arr[mynumber] = String(mynumber+1);
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought. Efficient and concise.

Comment: Might be faster to join/re-split the integer array in these examples than to convert one at a time. e.g. after the loops: `arr=arr.join('_').split('_');` and remove the `String(<number>)` steps.

Answer (score 2):

I would do as follows;

```js
var num = 10,
  dynar = [...Array(num)].map((_,i) => ++i+"");
console.log(dynar);
```

Answer (score 2):

A little late to this game, but there is REALLY cool stuff you can do with ES6 these days.

You can now fill an array of dynamic length with random numbers in one line of code!

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))
```

Comment: you could, `Array.from({length:10}, _=>-~(Math.random() * 100))`

Answer (score 1):

misread the question, corrected. Try:

```
var myNumber = 100,
    myarr = (function arr(i){return i ? arr(i-1).concat(i) : [i]}(myNumber));
```

Just for fun, if you extend `Array` like this:

```
Array.prototype.mapx = function(callback){
  return String(this).split(',').map(callback);
}
```

You could use:

```
var myNum = 100, 
    myarr = new Array(myNum).mapx(function(el,i){return i+1;});
```

Comment: ok, Now I change `mynumber = 100;`.. Please write the long string for me.

Comment: See my edit. It's not that efficient in terms of cpu cycles I suppose, but it's short.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=1; i<=mynumber; i++) {
   arr.push("" + i);
}
```

This seems to be faster in Chrome, according to [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/initialize-array-of-string), but please note that it is all very browser dependant.

There's 4 things you can change about this snippet:

1. Use `for` or `while`.
2. Use forward or backward loop (with backward creating sparse array at beginning)
3. Use `push` or direct access by index.
4. Use implicit stringification or explicitly call `toString`.

In each and every browser total speed would be combination of how much better each option for each item in this list performs in that particular browser.

TL;DR: it is probably not good idea to try to micro-optimize this particular piece.

Comment: why dose the variable i start with 1 rather than 0 ?

Comment: @JinnySong, did you read the question? It shows array that starts with `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and a solution I found (forgot where I found it) is this:

`Array.from(Array(mynumber), (val, index) => index + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether there is a built in Pythonic `range`-like function, there isn't.  You have to do it the brute force way.  Maybe [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) would be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have to get last element from array variable so my solution

> > 

```
var arr = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var mynumber = arr [arr .length - 1];
//var mynumber = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Some of us are referring to use [from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which is not good at the performance:**

```js
function getArrayViaFrom(input) {
  console.time('Execution Time');
  let output = Array.from(Array(input), (value, i) => (i + 1).toString())
  console.timeEnd('Execution Time');

  return output;
}

function getArrayViaFor(input) {
  console.time('Execution Time 1');
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    output.push(i.toString());
  }
  console.timeEnd('Execution Time 1');

  return output;
}

console.log(getArrayViaFrom(10)) // Takes 10x more than for that is 0.220ms
console.log(getArrayViaFor(10))  // Takes 10x less than From that is 0.020ms
```

Answer (score 0):

## updated = > june 2020

### if are you using node js you can create or append a string value with " ," operator then  inside the loop you can

```
for (var j = 0; j <= data.legth -1; j++) {
                    lang += data.lang  +", " ;

                }

 var langs = lang.split(',')
 console.log("Languages =>",  lang, typeof(lang), typeof(langs), langs) 
 console.log(lang[0]) // here access arrary by index value
```

you can see the type of  string and object

Answer (score -4):

The same way you would for all arrays you want to fill dynamically.
A for loop.
Suedo code is

```
arr =array()
for(i; i<max; i++){
 arr[]=i

}
```

that should help you on the way

Comment: use `var i` to avoid globals, use `new Array()` or even better `[]` instead of `array()`, give `i` a start value, specify an index here `arr[]=...`, make the values strings, the range isn't correct (you need to use `<=` or adjust the range by adding +1 or something)