# Javascript Add Array Element to Dynamically Named Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-declaration

Given

```
var input[[]];

$('some_selector').each(function() {
   var outer, inner; 
   outer=$(this).parent().attr('some_property');
   inner=$(this).attr('a_property');
   input[outer].push(inner);
});
```

An error is encountered during the `push` function. Is it because the specific `input[outer]` is not declared as array?

Also, the value of `outer` is not necessarily sorted. So within the loop, `outer` can sequentially have values of: *"property1","property2","property1","property3","property2"*...

In PHP terms, is there something equivalent to:

```
foreach () {
    $input[$outer][]=$inner;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I read that it's for declaring two-dimensional arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18163289/1503127

Comment: You are missing the `=`. And `var x = [[]];` is just declaring an array with an array in the first index.

Comment: Yup I've now seen what I've done wrong. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `outer` has values like "property1", etc., then `input` isn't an array. It's an object. Unlike PHP, there are no associative arrays in Javascript.

Try:

```
var input = {};
```

And yes, you'll need to *create* an array before pushing to it. You can do that in one "maybe it exists, maybe it doesn't" step like so:

```
input[outer] = input[outer] || [];
```

and then push as before:

```
input[outer].push(inner);
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot Paul. This was an AHA moment for me and pointed me to the right direction.  Just got to understood nature of Javascript arrays (index and associative) and objects.  For those who are confused like I was, you can read  http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/2865-javascript-data-structures-the-array-object.html and http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html