# Why isn’t this array access working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why doesn’t this method access work? No matter what we write into the method, the click never executes what we want.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    var Spiel1 = new TicTacToe();

    function TicTacToe() {
      var spielfeld = new Array[3][3];
      var zaehler = 0;
      this.Setzen = function(x, y) {
        document.getElementById("r0p0").innerHTML = "X";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="r0p0" onclick="Spiel1.Setzen(0,0)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is error in `var spielfeld = new Array[3][3];`.

Comment: Look in the F12 error console, `new Array[3][3];` is not valid syntax. See [Declare an empty two-dimensional array in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163234/declare-an-empty-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) is thats what your looking to do.

Comment: Holy titty thank you guys so much we wouldve never guessed that.

Answer (score 2):

There is error in `var spielfeld = new Array[3][3];` If you remove this line, your code will work.

**How to define multidimensional array?**

```
var spielfeld = new Array();
spielfeld[0] = new Array();
spielfeld[1] = new Array();
```

Another way, if you want to initialize array when declaring:

```
var a = new Array([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]);
var b = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
```

Answer (score 1):

just do :

```
spielfeld = new Array(3);
for (var i = 0 ; i< 3; i++){
 spielfeld[i] =  new Array(3);
}
```

or just

```
spielfeld = [[,,,],[,,,],[,,,]];
```

note that there is 3 commas because this array [,,] only has 2 elements!!

because that doesn't really matter..