# Initialize a two-dimensional array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create a two-dimensional array that gets initialized with booleans which are set to false. Currently I'm using this method of array creation:

```
const rows = 3
const cols = 5

const nestedArray = new Array(rows).fill(
    new Array(cols).fill(false)
)
```

The `nestedArray` looks fine, but as soon as I change the value of `nestedArray[0][2]`, the values of `nestedArray[1][2]` and `nestedArray[2][2]` also get changed.

I guess this is because the sub-arrays are identical, probably because they get filled into the parent array by reference and not by value.

What would be an elegant and efficient way of creating an array of non-identical sub-arrays instead?

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163234/declare-an-empty-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: Why dont you try using json?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use nested [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) calls:

```js
const rows = 3
const cols = 5

const nestedArray = Array.from({ length: rows }, () => 
  Array.from({ length: cols }, () => false)
);
  
nestedArray[0][1] = 'value'; // example of changing a single cell
  
console.log(nestedArray);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Array.from` method to create rows where second parameter is `map` method, and `Array.fill` for columns.

```js
const rows = 3
const cols = 5

const nestedArray = Array.from(Array(rows), _ => Array(cols).fill(false));
nestedArray[0][1] = true;
console.log(nestedArray)
```

Another approach would be to use spread syntax `...` on rows array so you can then use `map` method on that array.

```js
const rows = 3
const cols = 5

const nestedArray = [...Array(rows)].map(_ => Array(cols).fill(false))
nestedArray[0][1] = true;
console.log(nestedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already a lot of answers but maybe someone find this one more readable:

```
let rows = 3;
let columns = 5;
let rowTemplate = Array(columns).fill(false);
let matrix = Array.from(Array(rows), () => [...rowTemplate]);

matrix[1][3] = true;
/*
[
  [ false, false, false, false, false ],
  [ false, false, false, true, false ],
  [ false, false, false, false, false ]
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const nestedArray = Array(rows).fill(false).map(x => Array(cols).fill(false))
```

try this one

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```js
const rows = 3
const cols = 5

const nestedArray = new Array(rows).fill(0);

nestedArray.forEach((e, i, a) => a[i] = new Array(cols).fill(false));

console.log(nestedArray);
```

- First, initialize the array with dummy values
- Then, for each position initialize another nested array

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to *Ori Drori* answer, but a little bit shorter :

```js
const rows = 3;
const cols = 5;

const nestedArray = Array.from({length: rows}, () => Array(cols).fill(false));
nestedArray[1][2] = true;
console.log(nestedArray);
```