# Multidimensional array in javasscript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm learning from the book *JavaScript for Dummies*, and from the following code, it says

> `console.log( bestAlbumsByGenre[0][1] ) //will output: Patsy Cline:Sentimentally Yours`

```js
var bestAlbumsByGenre = []
bestAlbumsByGenre[0] = “Country”;
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][0] = “Johnny Cash: Live at Folsom Prison”
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][1] = “Patsy Cline: Sentimentally Yours”;
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][2] = “Hank Williams: I’ m Blue Inside”;
```

but in the console the output is: "o". Why is that, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code does not make any sense. [0][0] would be a string and it is acting like it is an array. The line should be `bestAlbumsByGenre[0] = [];`

Comment: It really doesn't, you are setting a character of a String to a String, where is that in Js for Dummies?

Comment: I've added your code to a snippet. Click Run code snippet and you'll see the errors.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you shouldn't do that when it's pseudo-code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see nothing in the question that indicates it's pseudo-code. Can you point out where that is mentioned?

Comment: javascript for dummies page 62, @Luca Kiebel

Comment: @HereticMonkey smart quotes.

Comment: If you replaced the `= "Country";` in the second line with `= [];`, it will do what you likely want.  This at least is an actual multidimensional array.

Comment: use `"` instead of `“`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare an empty two-dimensional array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163234/declare-an-empty-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up two different exercises.
The following line is resulting in the error:

```
bestAlbumsByGenre[0] = "Country";
```

I've cleaned up the code to make it work.

However, I think I would prefer an object, where each key represents the genre, and their value is an array.

```js
// Define the outer array
const bestAlbumsByGenre = [];

// Set the first element of the array as an array
bestAlbumsByGenre[0] = [];

// Add items to the first element (the array)
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][0] = "Johnny Cash: Live at Folsom Prison"
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][1] = "Patsy Cline: Sentimentally Yours";
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][2] = "Frank Williams: I’ m Blue Inside";

console.log(bestAlbumsByGenre[0][1]);

// Alternative approach
const reallyBestAlbumsByGenre = {
    rock: [],
};

reallyBestAlbumsByGenre.rock.push("Johnny Cash: Live at Folsom Prison");
reallyBestAlbumsByGenre.rock.push("Patsy Cline: Sentimentally Yours");
reallyBestAlbumsByGenre.rock.push("Frank Williams: I’ m Blue Inside");

console.log( reallyBestAlbumsByGenre.rock[1] );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cheers

Comment: This is by far the most thorough example. It shows how to fix the problem for the exercise using a 2D array as well as explains how to do it with an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually accessing a two dimensional array, but you are accessing the second character of a string.

Your are initializing a 1 dimensional array of string when you do:

When you did the following:

```
var bestAlbumsByGenre = [];
bestAlbumsByGenre[0] = "Country";
```

You assigned a string to the first element.

Subsequently, the other statements did nothing.

### Fix

The following fixes your error:"

```
var bestAlbumsByGenre = [[]]
bestAlbumsByGenre[0][0] = "Country";
```

Comment: yup, so how can i access, lets say: [country] [Johnny Cash..] from the mentioned code

Comment: @Mattey `var bestAlbumsByGenre = [[]]` , `bestAlbumsByGenre[0][0] = "Country";`

Comment: it does thanks, but can i access some inner elements within the array, maybe: bestAlbumsByGenre[0][1] //“Patsy Cline: Sentimentally Yours”; is there a way to do it

Comment: @Maltey: did you try it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better in this case to separate the creation of the outer array from the creation of the inner one?  It's odd if you then add the "Jazz" category and have to add that specifically to the outer array, but magically the initial "Country" one was there.  So I would do `var bestAlbumsByGenre = []` followed by `bestAlbumsByGenre[0] = []`.  It certainly seems a better approach for teaching beginners.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, it does work, thanks a lot. think I need to keep on learning about arrays and Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to organize albums by genre, it would make more sense to create an object with the genre as a key:

```
var bestAlbumsByGenre = {
    "Country": [
        "Johnny Cash: Live at Folsom Prison",
        "Patsy Cline: Sentimentally Yours",
        "Hank Williams: I’m Blue Inside",
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is certainly correct.  But the OP mentioned that this was an attempt to understand an example in a beginners' book.

Comment: Thanks a lot, hav a gud day.

Comment: agree with @ScottSauyet, I'll add that the exercise is about arrays[], not about objects{}