# 2D array with size from props only updates one dimension

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks

I am working through the Flavio Copes Pixel Art app in his React course and I'd like to add a button that can resize my "canvas".  The canvas is a 2D array that is initialized like so:

```
const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState(
Array(size)
  .fill()
  .map(() => Array(size).fill(0)));
```

The `size` variable is passed down as a prop from the parent component, which has a hook to manage the state from an input field.  The matrix is used to render "Pixel" components (30px x 30px divs) by mapping through each row/col like so:

```
<div className={css(styles.canvas)}>
      {matrix.map((row, rowIndex) =>
        row.map((_, colIndex) => {
          return (
            <Pixel
              key={`${rowIndex}-${colIndex}`}
              background={Colors[matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]]}
              onClick={() => changeColor(rowIndex, colIndex)}
            />
          );
        })
      )}
    </div>
```

I am able to update the width of the canvas (# of columns), but I think that the number of total Pixels remain constant and subsequent rows are added/subtracted that do not equal the number of columns.  You can replicate the error by inputting a new value into "Canvas Size" and clicking "Resize Canvas" on [my demo](https://peterarriaza.github.io/pixel-paint/).

Why do the number of rows differ from the number of columns?

All of the code is available in [my repo](https://github.com/PeterArriaza/pixel-paint).

Comment: Can you please take a look at this post about how to deal with 2 dimensional array initialization ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163234/declare-an-empty-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: The 2D array needs to be initialized with every entry = 0, which is why I am using the fill().map()

Answer (score 0):

I do not see change of columns/rows in your repo. This function should do the trick

```
const updateMatrixSize = (size) => {
  setMatrix(
    matrix.length > size
      ? matrix.slice(0, size).map(it => it.slice(0, size)))
      : [ 
         ...matrix.map(it => ([
                              ...it,
                              ...new Array(size - matrix.length).fill(0)
                             ])
         ),
         ...new Array(size - matrix.length).fill(0)
        ]
  )
}
```

PS you have a typo in your repo

```
props.setMsatrixState(newMatrix);
```