# Use of JavaScript new Array(n) Declaration but with 2 sizes

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a student and i was freaking out doing this exercise.
Is there any way of sizing an array with the new Array(n) declaration but taking in consideration a table with 2 axis (i and j)?

```
let quinielas = new Array(20);

function generaResultados(quinielas) {
  for (let i = 0; i < quinielas.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < quinielas[i].length; j++) {
      quinielas[i][j] = generaSimbolo();
    }
  }
  console.table(quinielas);
}

generaResultados(quinielas);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare an empty two-dimensional array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163234/declare-an-empty-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't support multidimensional arrays the way you're thinking of them; each element of an array *can* be another array, but they're not required to be as in a true multidimensional array in other languages.  (The same goes for array length; the boundaries of the array aren't predefined as they are in some other languages.)

To correct your code, all you'd need to do is declare that each element of `quinielas` is itself a new Array.

```js
let quinielas = new Array(20);

function generaResultados(quinielas) {
  for (let i = 0; i < quinielas.length; i++) {
    quinielas[i] = new Array(20); // <-- add this
    for (let j = 0; j < quinielas[i].length; j++) { 
      quinielas[i][j] = "something";
    }
  }
  console.log(quinielas);
}

generaResultados(quinielas);
```

(Note though that the parameter in `new Array()` is a bit [ambiguous](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#array.constructor) and should probably be avoided; it does set what `.length` will return, but otherwise doesn't behave as you'd expect. All the elements are still undefined, and logging the array itself still just returns `[]` just as if you had omitted the param.   (This was a bit of a "today I learned" for me; up until now, after decades of coding in JS, I had been under the impression that `new Array()` and `new Array(20)` gave identical results.)