# how to push a variable into array - Insert blank row in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

According to this post [Insert row between different data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531722/insert-row-between-different-data) I'm able to insert an empty data row between some rows in a spreadsheet (based on a condition).

I'm trying to make this script adaptable based on the number of columns.

I mean, if I have 3 columns I have to write

```
newValues.push(['','','']);
```

If I have 5 columns (i.e.) I have to change in

```
newValues.push(['','','','','']);
```

I want to make this change automatic.
I've tried with something like

```
var blankRow = ' " " ';

for (var x = 0; x<lastCol; x++){
blankRow = blankRow + ',""';
}

.....

newValues.push([blankRow]);
```

when I run the script gives me an error.

Any idea how can I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please provide what (if any) error you are getting.

Seems like it would be a range error. If so, then it's most likely how you build your new array. At a glance, I suspect you are getting 1 column too much, because you start with 1 column already added, and your `for` loop starts off at `0`, which means you get `lastCol+1` length when you have `lastCol` range.

So if we follow your code, and you want to `setValues()` for 3 columns you have

```
Start: blankRow = ' " " '
x = 0 blankRow = ' " ", " " '
x = 1 blankRow = ' " ", " ", " " '
x = 2 blankRow = ' " ", " ", " ", " " '
```

so as you can see, you have a 3 column range, yet you are trying to set 4 columns worth of values. I also recommend getting rid of the `" "` in favour of `""` as it will leave a blank value instead of a space in the cells.

Comment: I've fixed the for cycle (checked with Logger). When i try to run newValues.push([blankRow]); or newValues.push(blankRow); I get the error "uncorrect length of interval, it was 1 but it should be 5" (error message translated from italian).