# Excel VBA>Javascript: Loop through rows inserting rows where cell values differ

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets-query, vba

I'm struggling to get javascript to run in Googlesheets to do the following:

- Loop through column A:A comparing the above cell value to the below cell value
- Where, for example say A2 isn't the same as A3 then insert two rows beneath it
- Copy the last value above the first blank row and offset down one row into  the first new inserted blank row and paste it.

Now I managed to find this example of something similar to what I'm trying to do at the basic level (hence my question here):
[Insert row between different data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531722/insert-row-between-different-data) and it's from that that I got this:

```
function doSomething() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySheetID'),
     tab = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0], // Get the first tab
     values = tab.getRange(2, 1, tab.getLastRow(), 3).getDisplayValues(),     //Get the values beginning in the second row because of the headers
     newValues = [], // Empty array where we're gonna push the new values
     lastName;
    // Loop through all the values
 for(var i = 0; i <values.length; i++){
   // If the last name is different from the current name or the last date is different from the current date add an empty "row" to the new array
   if((lastName != undefined) && (values[i][1] != lastName)){
     newValues.push(['','','']);
   }
   //Add the current row to the new array
   newValues.push(values[i]);
   //Sets the lastDate and lastName to the current values for the next evaluation
   lastName = values[i][1];
 }
 //Sets the new values
 tab.getRange(2,1,newValues.length,3).setValues(newValues)

},
```

This does insert a new row but at every other row so I suspect that it's picking up on data that's in Column C (which is different on every row) as opposed to the data in Column A.
I've Googled a lot to find out even how to open a sheet with the `SpreadsheetApp.openById` bit and so I'm asking for help or if you can point out bits of the above code to look into. I know it's been very helpfully commented but as I said I'm completely new to javascript.

If it helps there is a an Excel/VBA script that works perfectly:

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("A" & i - 1).Value <> Range("A" & i).Value Then
            Rows(i).Resize(2).Insert
            Range("M" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

They're some diagrams in the below VBA question but can't see how to do that here, sorry: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1034334-insert-blank-row-offset-copy-paste.html#post4964822

Thanks for your time and any help, I have no experience with javascript, sorry.

Max.

- QUICK UPDATE 09/12/17:

I've managed to get parts one and two off of my "Wish List" completed now. I don't fully understand it but I've commented where I can to remind myself later:

```js
function importFromSDE() {
  
// Open the Google Sheet
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('mySheetID'),
     
// Get the tab by name
     tab = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Testing'), 
 
// Get the values beginning in the second row because of the headers     
// Values from Row 2, Column 1, Down to last row, across 11 columns
     values = tab.getRange(2,1,tab.getLastRow(),11).getDisplayValues(),
     
// Empty array where we're gonna push the new values       
     newValues = [],
     lastT1Item;

// Loop through all the values
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){

// If the last name is different from the current name or the last date is different from the current date add an empty "row" to the new array
   if((lastT1Item != undefined) && (values[i][0] != lastT1Item)){
     newValues.push(['','','','','','','','','','','']);
      newValues.push(['','','','','','','','','','','']);
   }

//Add the current row to the new array
   newValues.push(values[i]);

//Sets the lastT1Item to the current values for the next evaluation
   lastT1Item = values[i][0];
    
 }
  
//Sets the new values
 tab.getRange(2,1,newValues.length,11).setValues(newValues)

}
```