# do <something> N times (declarative syntax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Is there a way in Javascript to write something like this easily:

```
[1,2,3].times do {
  something();
}
```

Any library that might support some similar syntax maybe?

**Update:** to clarify - I would like `something()` to be called 1,2 and 3 times respectively for each array element iteration

Comment: I would say there is no feature like this in JS, and it's a top 5 missing feature. It is very useful for testing software, more than anything.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This answer is based on `Array.forEach`, without any library, just native [vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com/).

To basically call `something()` 3 times, use:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(i) {
  something();
});
```

considering the following function:

```
function something(){ console.log('something') }
```

The output will be:

```
something
something
something
```

---

To complete this questions, here's a way to do call `something()` 1, 2 and 3 times respectively:

#### It's 2017, you may use ES6:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(i => Array(i).fill(i).forEach(_ => {
  something()
}))
```

#### or in good old ES5:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(i) {
  Array(i).fill(i).forEach(function() {
    something()
  })
}))
```

In both cases, the output will be

The output will be:

```
something

something
something

something
something
something
```

(once, then twice, then 3 times)

Comment: This is incorrect because it doesn't satisfy this part of the question: 'I would like something() to be called 1,2 and 3 times'. Using this code `something` is only called 3 times, it should be called 6 times.

Comment: Then I guess it's been selected as _best answer_ as it may be a good cleaner start.

Comment: You could also use `[...Array(i)]` or `Array(i).fill()`, depending on your needs for the actual indexes.

Comment: If you're not interested in any arguments passed, use `.forEach(something)`

Answer (score 155):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
const times = 10;

for(let i = 0; i < times; i++){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: thank you! I would like to benefit from a declarative syntax (just like Jasmine etc)

Comment: right, but a functional for-loop declarative syntax would also be much better

Comment: Yes please, I'm sick and tired of being forced declarative shit all over for no reason. It's a great tool to use when you need it, but a tool not a holy mandate.

Comment: Or use a `while(times--)` if you want it in less keystrokes!

Comment: Just profiled this, on both Chrome and Firefox currently, this imperative syntax is faster than any of the the declarative syntax versions described in this question.  tl;dr: Yes, use a `for` loop.

Comment: unpopular but a bunch of people using React probably want to know the declarative/expression syntax so they can include it in a .jsx expression in the render function

Answer (score 133):

Possible ES6 alternative.

```
Array.from(Array(3)).forEach((x, i) => {
  something();
});
```

And, if you want it "to be called 1,2 and 3 times respectively".

```
Array.from(Array(3)).forEach((x, i) => {
  Array.from(Array(i+1)).forEach((x, i2) => {
    console.log(`Something ${ i } ${ i2 }`)
  });
});
```

#### Update:

Taken from [filling-arrays-with-undefined](http://2ality.com/2018/12/creating-arrays.html#filling-arrays-with-undefined:)

This seems to be a more optimised way of creating the initial array, I've also updated this to use the second parameter map function suggested by @felix-eve.

```
Array.from({ length: 3 }, (x, i) => {
  something();
});
```

Comment: I should caveat this by saying this is ok if you're just quickly scripting something up, but the performance is horrible, so don't use it for intensive recursion or in production at all probably.

Comment: If you're going for ES6, you can use map() instead of forEach()

Comment: `map` and `forEach` are both ES5

Comment: Indeed, it's `Array.from` that falls under ES6, and in this instance, the arrow functions are really unnecessary. They're just used for terseness.

Comment: If terseness is the goal (and actually, even if it isn't), pass the function instead of calling it: `Array.from(Array(3)).forEach(something)`

Comment: Works with react expression rendering as well.

Comment: [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) has an optional second parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to execute a map function on each element of the array, so there is no need to use forEach. You can just do: `Array.from({length: 3}, () => somthing() )`

Comment: `Array.from({length: 3}, something)`

Answer (score 80):

#### The easiest way is by [destructuring the Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment),

which automatically *sets* `undefined` for each item, if the item's value  was not set:

```js
[...Array(5)].map((item, i) => console.log(item, i))
```

The [`keys` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) can also be used to generate an Array of indices values:

```js
[...Array(3).keys()] // [0, 1, 2]
```

Alternatively, create an Array and [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) all items with `undefined` before using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

[Read detailed reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/104380) why `map` is skipping never-defined array items

⚠️ *`Array.fill` has no **IE** support*

```js
Array(5).fill().map((item, i) => console.log(item, i))
```

---

If you want to make the above more ***"declarative"***, my currently opinion-based solution would be:

```js
const iterate = times => callback => [...Array(times)].map((n,i) => callback(i))

iterate(3)(console.log)
```

---

#### Using old-school (reverse) loop:

```js
// run 5 times:
for( let i=5; i--; )
   console.log(i)
```

#### Or as a declarative *"while"*:

```js
const run = (cb, ...args) => count => { while(count--) cb(...args) }

// executes the callback with whatever arguments, 3 times
run(console.log, 1,2,3)(3)
```

Comment: For piece of mind I ran a uuid function **50k times** to make sure it never duplicated a uuid. So I profiled the top loop vs the bottom just for kicks, just running in the middle of a normal page load using chrome dev tools **if im not being dumb I think its ~1.2billion compares using Array.indexOf()** plus generating 50k uuids. **newschool = 1st-5561.2ms 2nd-5426.8ms | oldschool = 1st-4966.3ms / 2nd-4929.0ms** Moral of the story if u are not in the billion+ range u would never notice a difference running these 200, 1k, even 10k times to do something. Figured someone might be curious like me.

Comment: That is correct and has been known for many years. The different approaches were not presented for speed benefits but for older browsers' support.

Comment: Odviously everyone that reads this thread, knows you didn't present the examples to compare their speed. I just happened to use them to run a little test and figured I would share some info that someone down the road might find interesting. I'm not really correct because I wasn't really answering a question just displaying information and giving a reminder to not sweat the speed of a loop when your only doing a few things that will end in a couple ms anyways. It's not really known either because the same test a year ago in ie may find one 50% slower because browsers change all the time.

Comment: or `for(var i=10; i--; console.log(i));`

Answer (score 26):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com):

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], (item) => {
   doSomeThing(item);
});

//Or:
_.each([1, 2, 3], doSomeThing);
```

Or if you want to **do something N times**:

```
const N = 10;
_.times(N, () => {
   doSomeThing();
});

//Or shorter:
_.times(N, doSomeThing);
```

Answer (score 18):

Since you mention Underscore:

Assuming `f` is the function you want to call:

```
_.each([1,2,3], function (n) { _.times(n, f) });
```

will do the trick. For example, with `f = function (x) { console.log(x); }`, you will get on your console:
`0 0 1 0 1 2`

Comment: Indeed, I thought you wanted separation.

Comment: `_(3).times(function(n){return n;});` should do the trick. [See the docs here.](http://underscorejs.org/#times)

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 15):

You can also do the same thing with destructuring as follows

```
[...Array(3)].forEach( _ => console.log('do something'));
```

or if you need index

```
[...Array(3)].forEach(( _, index) => console.log('do something'));
```

Answer (score 14):

How about a simple while.

```js
let times = 5;

while (times--) {

    console.log(times+1)

}
```

References on how this works: [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [Decrement (--)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)

---

**Edit**: If there's a possibility for `times` to be manipulated elsewhere, it's safer to use `times-- > 0` instead of `times--` to prevent an infinite loop if the `times` drops below `0`

Answer (score 9):

If you can't use Underscorejs, you can implement it yourself. By attaching new methods to the Number and String prototypes, you could do it like this (using ES6 arrow functions):

```
// With String
"5".times( (i) => console.log("number "+i) );

// With number variable
var five = 5;
five.times( (i) => console.log("number "+i) );

// With number literal (parentheses required)
(5).times( (i) => console.log("number "+i) );
```

You simply have to create a function expression (of whatever name) and assign it to whatever property name (on the prototypes) you would like to access it as:

```
var timesFunction = function(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== "function" ) {
    throw new TypeError("Callback is not a function");
  } else if( isNaN(parseInt(Number(this.valueOf()))) ) {
    throw new TypeError("Object is not a valid number");
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < Number(this.valueOf()); i++) {
    callback(i);
  }
};

String.prototype.times = timesFunction;
Number.prototype.times = timesFunction;
```

Comment: I would have to reinvestigate how bad it is it to patch the prototype, but usually it's just fine

Answer (score 1):

Just use a nested loop (maybe enclosed in a function)

```
function times( fct, times ) {
  for( var i=0; i<times.length; ++i ) {
    for( var j=0; j<times[i]; ++j ) {
      fct();
    }
  }
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
times( doSomething, [1,2,3] );
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (ES6)

---

##### `Array.from()` creates a new Array instance from either an iterable object (like `Array`, `Set`, or `Map`) or from an Array-like object that has a native length property (such as `String` or `Function`).

You can also attach a callback function that will be called on each iterated element:

```js
function doSomething(val) {
  console.log(val);
}

Array.from([1,2,3], doSomething); // 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
times = function () {
    var length = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arguments[i]; j++) {
            dosomthing();
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
times(3,4);
times(1,2,3,4);
times(1,3,5,7,9);
```

Comment: +1 - This utilizes the native JavaScript ability to call functions with variable amounts of parameters. No extra library needed. Nice solution

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all good and well and IMO @Andreas is the best, but many times in JS we have to do things asynchronously, in that case, async has you covered:

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times

```
const async = require('async');

async.times(5, function(n, next) {
    createUser(n, function(err, user) {
        next(err, user);
    });
}, function(err, users) {
    // we should now have 5 users
});
```

These 'times' features arent very useful for most application code, but should be useful for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
const loop (fn, times) => {
  if (!times) { return }
  fn()
  loop(fn, times - 1)
}

loop(something, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic library called Ramda, which is similar to Underscore and Lodash, but is more powerful.

```
const R = require('ramda');

R.call(R.times(() => {
    console.log('do something')
}), 5);
```

Ramda contains plenty of useful functions. See [Ramda documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/)

Comment: I love this library as a modern and elegant FP solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we can use some ES6 syntax like the spread operator, we'll want to do something as many times as the sum of all numbers in the collection.

In this case if times is equal to `[1,2,3]`, the total number of times will be 6, i.e. 1+2+3.

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} times
 * @param {cb} function
 */
function doTimes(times, cb) {
  // Get the sum of all the times
  const totalTimes = times.reduce((acc, time) => acc + time);
  // Call the callback as many times as the sum
  [...Array(totalTimes)].map(cb);
}

doTimes([1,2,3], () => console.log('something'));
// => Prints 'something' 6 times
```

This post should be [helpful](https://itnext.io/heres-why-mapping-a-constructed-array-doesn-t-work-in-javascript-f1195138615a) if the logic behind constructing and spreading an array isn't apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late for the party but I want to leave here my sollution too.

This function will do a task and return it's result as an array.

```
function doN<T>(
  n: number,
  task: ( i: number ) => T
): T[] {
  return [ ...Array( n ) ].map( ( _, index ) => ( task( index ) ) )
}
```

In my case I'm using it to render a React component N times:

```
const components = doN<ReactNode>(
  products.lenght,
  ( iteration ) => (<MyComponent key={products[ iteration ].id}>
    {products[ iteration ].name}
  </MyComponent>)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var times = [1,2,3];

for(var i = 0; i < times.length;  i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < times[i];j++) {
     // do something
  }
}
```

Using jQuery `.each()`

```
$([1,2,3]).each(function(i, val) {
  for(var j = 0; j < val;j++) {
     // do something
  }
});
```

OR

```
var x = [1,2,3];

$(x).each(function(i, val) {
  for(var j = 0; j < val;j++) {
     // do something
  }
});
```

## EDIT

You can do like below with pure JS:

```
var times = [1,2,3];
times.forEach(function(i) {
   // do something
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

Array.forEach

example:

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {  
    console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);  
}  
[2, 5, 9].forEach(logArrayElements)
```

or with jQuery

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: It looks like `forEach` is only supported in IE from version 9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score -1):

```
// calls doSomething 42 times
Array( 42 ).join( "x" ).split( "" ).forEach( doSomething );
```

and

```
// creates 42 somethings
var somethings = Array( 42 ).join( "x" ).split( "" ).map( () => buildSomething(); );
```

or ( via https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066663/275501 )

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 42}).forEach( doSomething );
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `Array.from` and `.forEach`.

```js
let length = 5;
Array.from({length}).forEach((v, i) => {
  console.log(`#${i}`);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**TypeScript Implementation:**

For those of you who are interested in how to implement `String.times` and `Number.times` in a way that is type safe and works with the `thisArg`, here ya go:

```
declare global {
    interface Number {
        times: (callbackFn: (iteration: number) => void, thisArg?: any) => void;
    }
    interface String {
        times: (callbackFn: (iteration: number) => void, thisArg?: any) => void;
    }
}

Number.prototype.times = function (callbackFn, thisArg) {
    const num = this.valueOf()
    if (typeof callbackFn !== "function" ) {
        throw new TypeError("callbackFn is not a function")
    }
    if (num < 0) {
        throw new RangeError('Must not be negative')
    }
    if (!isFinite(num)) {
        throw new RangeError('Must be Finite')
    }
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        throw new RangeError('Must not be NaN')
    }

    [...Array(num)].forEach((_, i) => callbackFn.bind(thisArg, i + 1)())
    // Other elegant solutions
    // new Array<null>(num).fill(null).forEach(() => {})
    // Array.from({length: num}).forEach(() => {})
}

String.prototype.times = function (callbackFn, thisArg) {
    let num = parseInt(this.valueOf())
    if (typeof callbackFn !== "function" ) {
        throw new TypeError("callbackFn is not a function")
    }
    if (num < 0) {
        throw new RangeError('Must not be negative')
    }
    if (!isFinite(num)) {
        throw new RangeError('Must be Finite')
    }
    // num is NaN if `this` is an empty string 
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        num = 0
    }

    [...Array(num)].forEach((_, i) => callbackFn.bind(thisArg, i + 1)())
    // Other elegant solutions
    // new Array<null>(num).fill(null).forEach(() => {})
    // Array.from({length: num}).forEach(() => {})
}
```

A link to the **TypeScript Playground** with some examples can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=51&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoeB8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgHICuAtmpTvoV2UcyAM4AueAAowmCBjABrAGIlhIohRhQeKBfBIs2MAJTwAvAD54ANxRFgAGnhkAFkX4BBGIgD8wqCQCeBk%20aWwADcnAQAvmHE5JQ0dPAAymQwpIgcXNy8AoriEJK0cppKKmpEGsLarJT%20phZWtg5Orh5evjWBVqFckZG4TFUwAHQADjAoZOM%20wyCDPHz8RvBUjCRg6iSiufky8g2OLm4GeFxgGvxkWiyLjfyDZpiMIADyVCJ6UURUomRTIChfWykhXgAEJDIZ4AAiZardaQ%20BHKLcexjADuWhA6IAKr8AKIwMYwESQwEFeTEBYkcbwKBLFZrMokSHvbofL4iSrwAA88AADIiMoQHGiMeiAEreRAgfGEkQAcgAsoxzlpqWwMYhSmYQHKWYRIlxPqIQU5ZKRlCAOSw9ALBXYUSh0SRMfAJSQpTKUETFcqLuqzSQLbqogbCEalPx6FB6FbmDb0nbhY7Ra7JdKCV75UqVVS-Qxo8HWVEANqDMuuVQ%20WN6AC6gyoXtxtHsIhEAH1bER2qSdiRBmhSMARDdmp34ABqeAARj0bz1BAA9Av4E8HOwQBAQJryPB%20CgIIx1vwokuUxWoD4udo8sZq-WiHkrXk9PXG83W%201sOF5-BT%20efPWYzMCI2Cbu6DgVCw36vjATZgC2bxGKYX7vL0SQpO6IxjBMPzTLMWQLBCMIMhomwSECuz2k0hwJgQm4XJyELDLA-AgAAkuQw77HcDzPK8Npst8vz-PAPbAmCELQvScIIrRGRJk6Lo4tMnpEiS5FkhsTiqhctLEXCP6hgQ4acjy-JyciIrOuKaaqVmvo6fA6rOpqPDaoW%20qCSIJr8AGFrVragoKSmboehm3rZnm8B%20RQHkRCey6ctpUb0MQXwAAY3OlFI0hsIDMMMPy7skqTwF5TgpQFFmEIxfIhrgJZloM-7VnWDawe%207adt2Gm9v2g5cdRiBjpOM5zglK5rjA8Ablu3gXHuB5HhN1nwP%20V6MDed5UA%20EBPhAL7tXBCGft%20E3-oBKDAaBIDgfYkHMNBR2dadqENaepwkDmW5YqiKCLAAtAATLgp4ub9KD4fMH5IaJZz7jMqCIPKlS6MIjgMXNbk6gJp4pVDAgwwEn2LYjKDI3KqOUOjyjwClurvKeHE7YGPwE-wROmCTCODEjKM6NT8AY-AzPmj8DO4CTFwgAAHlABWbli%20yLNgO3asIACskT0XYf2LCDZB-ezIj6Yy3z7MIuF-F8svy8Miv7J2JTrIFcNfTzfNyvBD7AFRQjwHKexOD%203Obrz5PEhaqjrAAxMIkJO5QpQaKhti2wrIBK8HDWg8ucpysbiHE-DYee%20cGGIDTFz07jefAwXcyE0XXMl2TFPl6kVcalqOOM3nGsNwRnNu6T4ftyV7pVxLuCy8MXoXNg8DhKEQA)

This post implements solutions posted by: **Andreas Bergström**, **vinyll**, **Ozay Duman**, & **SeregPie**

Answer (score -2):

Given a function `something`:

```
function something() { console.log("did something") }
```

And a new method `times` added to the `Array` prototype:

```
Array.prototype.times = function(f){
  for(v of this) 
    for(var _ of Array(v))
      f();
}
```

This code:

```
[1,2,3].times(something)
```

Outputs this:

```
did something
did something
did something
did something
did something
did something
```

Which I *think* answers your updated question (5 years later) but I wonder how useful it is to have this work on an array? Wouldn't the effect be the same as calling `[6].times(something)`, which in turn could be written as:

```
for(_ of Array(6)) something();
```

(although the use of `_` as a junk variable will probably clobber lodash or underscore if you're using it)

Comment: It is consider to be bad practice to add custom methods to a native JS object.

Comment: You can use `let` as in `for (let _ of Array(6)) something()` to prevent clobbering lodash outside of the for at least.