# Creating range in JavaScript - strange syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I've run into the following code in the es-discuss mailing list:

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }).map(Number.call, Number);
```

This produces

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why is this the result of the code? What's happening here?

Comment: IMO `Array.apply(null, Array(30)).map(Number.call, Number)` is easier to read since it avoids pretending that a plain object is an Array.

Comment: @fncomp Please don't use either to _actually_ create a range. Not only is it slower than the straightforward approach - it's not nearly as easy to understand. It's hard to understand the syntax (well, really the API and not the syntax) here which makes this an interesting question but terrible production code IMO.

Comment: Yes, not suggesting anyone uses it, but thought it was still easier to read, relative to the object literal version.

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would want to do this. The amount of time it takes to create the array this way could have been done in a slightly less sexy but much quicker way: http://jsperf.com/basic-vs-extreme

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Understanding this "hack" requires understanding several things:

1. Why we don't just do `Array(5).map(...)`
2. How `Function.prototype.apply` handles arguments
3. How `Array` handles multiple arguments
4. How the `Number` function handles arguments
5. What `Function.prototype.call` does

They're rather advanced topics in javascript, so this will be more-than-rather long. We'll start from the top. Buckle up!

### 1. Why not just `Array(5).map`?

What's an array, really? A regular object, containing integer keys, which map to values. It has other special features, for instance the magical `length` variable, but at it's core, it's a regular `key => value` map, just like any other object. Let's play with arrays a little, shall we?

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.hasOwnProperty(0); //true
arr[0]; //'a'
Object.keys(arr); //['0', '1', '2']
arr.length; //3, implies arr[3] === undefined

//we expand the array by 1 item
arr.length = 4;
arr[3]; //undefined
arr.hasOwnProperty(3); //false
Object.keys(arr); //['0', '1', '2']
```

We get to the inherent difference between the number of items in the array, `arr.length`, and the number of `key=>value` mappings the array has, which can be different than `arr.length`.

Expanding the array via `arr.length` *does not* create any new `key=>value` mappings, so it's not that the array has undefined values, it *does not have these keys*. And what happens when you try to access a non-existent property? You get `undefined`.

Now we can lift our heads a little, and see why functions like `arr.map` don't walk over these properties. If `arr[3]` was merely undefined, and the key existed, all these array functions would just go over it like any other value:

```
//just to remind you
arr; //['a', 'b', 'c', undefined];
arr.length; //4
arr[4] = 'e';

arr; //['a', 'b', 'c', undefined, 'e'];
arr.length; //5
Object.keys(arr); //['0', '1', '2', '4']

arr.map(function (item) { return item.toUpperCase() });
//["A", "B", "C", undefined, "E"]
```

I intentionally used a method call to further prove the point that the key itself was never there: Calling `undefined.toUpperCase` would have raised an error, but it didn't. To prove *that*:

```
arr[5] = undefined;
arr; //["a", "b", "c", undefined, "e", undefined]
arr.hasOwnProperty(5); //true
arr.map(function (item) { return item.toUpperCase() });
//TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined
```

And now we get to my point: How `Array(N)` does things. [Section 15.4.2.2](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.2.2) describes the process. There's a bunch of mumbo jumbo we don't care about, but if you manage to read between the lines (or you can just trust me on this one, but don't), it basically boils down to this:

```
function Array(len) {
    var ret = [];
    ret.length = len;
    return ret;
}
```

(operates under the assumption (which is checked in the actual spec) that `len` is a valid uint32, and not just any number of value)

So now you can see why doing `Array(5).map(...)` wouldn't work - we don't define `len` items on the array, we don't create the `key => value` mappings, we simply alter the `length` property.

Now that we have that out of the way, let's look at the second magical thing:

### 2. How `Function.prototype.apply` works

What `apply` does is basically take an array, and unroll it as a function call's arguments. That means that the following are pretty much the same:

```
function foo (a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
foo(0, 1, 2); //3
foo.apply(null, [0, 1, 2]); //3
```

Now, we can ease the process of seeing how `apply` works by simply logging the `arguments` special variable:

```
function log () {
    console.log(arguments);
}

log.apply(null, ['mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']);
 //["mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"]

//arguments is a pseudo-array itself, so we can use it as well
(function () {
    log.apply(null, arguments);
})('mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb');
 //["mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"]

//a NodeList, like the one returned from DOM methods, is also a pseudo-array
log.apply(null, document.getElementsByTagName('script'));
 //[script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script]

//carefully look at the following two
log.apply(null, Array(5));
//[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
//note that the above are not undefined keys - but the value undefined itself!

log.apply(null, {length : 5});
//[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

It's easy to prove my claim in the second-to-last example:

```
function ahaExclamationMark () {
    console.log(arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments.hasOwnProperty(0));
}

ahaExclamationMark.apply(null, Array(2)); //2, true
```

(yes, pun intended). The `key => value` mapping may not have existed in the array we passed over to `apply`, but it certainly exists in the `arguments` variable. It's the same reason the last example works: The keys do not exist on the object we pass, but they do exist in `arguments`.

Why is that? Let's look at [Section 15.3.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3), where `Function.prototype.apply` is defined. Mostly things we don't care about, but here's the interesting portion:

> 4. Let len be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of argArray with argument "length".

Which basically means: `argArray.length`. The spec then proceeds to do a simple `for` loop over `length` items, making a `list` of corresponding values (`list` is some internal voodoo, but it's basically an array). In terms of very, very loose code:

```
Function.prototype.apply = function (thisArg, argArray) {
    var len = argArray.length,
        argList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        argList[i] = argArray[i];
    }

    //yeah...
    superMagicalFunctionInvocation(this, thisArg, argList);
};
```

So all we need to mimic an `argArray` in this case is an object with a `length` property. And now we can see why the values are undefined, but the keys aren't, on `arguments`: We create the `key=>value` mappings.

Phew, so this might not have been shorter than the previous part. But there'll be cake when we finish, so be patient! However, after the following section (which'll be short, I promise) we can begin dissecting the expression. In case you forgot, the question was how does the following work:

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }).map(Number.call, Number);
```

### 3. How `Array` handles multiple arguments

So! We saw what happens when you pass a `length` argument to `Array`, but in the expression, we pass several things as arguments (an array of 5 `undefined`, to be exact). [Section 15.4.2.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.2.1) tells us what to do. The last paragraph is all that matters to us, and it's worded *really* oddly, but it kind of boils down to:

```
function Array () {
    var ret = [];
    ret.length = arguments.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
        ret[i] = arguments[i];
    }

    return ret;
}

Array(0, 1, 2); //[0, 1, 2]
Array.apply(null, [0, 1, 2]); //[0, 1, 2]
Array.apply(null, Array(2)); //[undefined, undefined]
Array.apply(null, {length:2}); //[undefined, undefined]
```

Tada! We get an array of several undefined values, and we return an array of these undefined values.

### The first part of the expression

Finally, we can decipher the following:

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 5 })
```

We saw that it returns an array containing 5 undefined values, with keys all in existence.

Now, to the second part of the expression:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].map(Number.call, Number)
```

This will be the easier, non-convoluted part, as it doesn't so much rely on obscure hacks.

### 4. How `Number` treats input

Doing `Number(something)` ([section 15.7.1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1.1)) converts `something` to a number, and that is all. How it does that is a bit convoluted, especially in the cases of strings, but the operation is defined in [section 9.3](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3) in case you're interested.

### 5. Games of `Function.prototype.call`

`call` is `apply`'s brother, defined in [section 15.3.4.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4). Instead of taking an array of arguments, it just takes the arguments it received, and passes them forward.

Things get interesting when you chain more than one `call` together, crank the weird up to 11:

```
function log () {
    console.log(this, arguments);
}
log.call.call(log, {a:4}, {a:5});
//{a:4}, [{a:5}]
//^---^  ^-----^
// this   arguments
```

This is quite wtf worthy until you grasp what's going on. `log.call` is just a function, equivalent to any other function's `call` method, and as such, has a `call` method on itself as well:

```
log.call === log.call.call; //true
log.call === Function.call; //true
```

And what does `call` do? It accepts a `thisArg` and a bunch of arguments, and calls its parent function. We can define it via `apply`  (again, very loose code, won't work):

```
Function.prototype.call = function (thisArg) {
    var args = arguments.slice(1); //I wish that'd work
    return this.apply(thisArg, args);
};
```

Let's track how this goes down:

```
log.call.call(log, {a:4}, {a:5});
  this = log.call
  thisArg = log
  args = [{a:4}, {a:5}]

  log.call.apply(log, [{a:4}, {a:5}])

    log.call({a:4}, {a:5})
      this = log
      thisArg = {a:4}
      args = [{a:5}]

      log.apply({a:4}, [{a:5}])
```

### The later part, or the `.map` of it all

It's not over yet. Let's see what happens when you supply a function to most array methods:

```
function log () {
    console.log(this, arguments);
}

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr.forEach(log);
//window, ['a', 0, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
//window, ['b', 1, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
//window, ['c', 2, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
//^----^  ^-----------------------^
// this         arguments
```

If we don't provide a `this` argument ourselves, it defaults to `window`. Take note of the order in which the arguments are provided to our callback, and let's weird it up all the way to 11 again:

```
arr.forEach(log.call, log);
//'a', [0, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
//'b', [1, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
//'b', [2, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
// ^    ^
```

Whoa whoa whoa...let's back up a bit. What's going on here? We can see in [section 15.4.4.18](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18), where `forEach` is defined, the following pretty much happens:

```
var callback = log.call,
    thisArg = log;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    callback.call(thisArg, arr[i], i, arr);
}
```

So, we get this:

```
log.call.call(log, arr[i], i, arr);
//After one `.call`, it cascades to:
log.call(arr[i], i, arr);
//Further cascading to:
log(i, arr);
```

Now we can see how `.map(Number.call, Number)` works:

```
Number.call.call(Number, arr[i], i, arr);
Number.call(arr[i], i, arr);
Number(i, arr);
```

Which returns the transformation of `i`, the current index, to a number.

### In conclusion,

The expression

```
Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }).map(Number.call, Number);
```

Works in two parts:

```
var arr = Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }); //1
arr.map(Number.call, Number); //2
```

The first part creates an array of 5 undefined items. The second goes over that array and takes its indices, resulting in an array of element indices:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @Zirak Please help me in understanding the following `ahaExclamationMark.apply(null, Array(2)); //2, true`. Why does it return `2` and `true` respectively? Aren't you passing only one argument i.e `Array(2)` here?

Comment: @Geek We only pass one argument to `apply`, but that argument is "splatted" into two arguments passed to the function. You can see that more easily in the first `apply` examples. The first `console.log` then shows that indeed, we received two arguments (the two array items), and the second `console.log` shows that the array has a `key=>value` mapping in the 1st slot (as explained in the 1st part of the answer).

Comment: Due to [(some) request](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17?m=11996892#11996892), you can now enjoy the audio version: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24522528/SO-answer.mp3

Comment: Note that passing a NodeList, which is a host object, to a native method as in `log.apply(null, document.getElementsByTagName('script'));` is not required to work and does not work in some browsers, and `[].slice.call(NodeList)` to turn a NodeList into an array will not work in them either.

Comment: @RobG This is why I highjacked jQuery's idea for 'arrayLike': `Object.prototype.isArraylike =  function (obj) {
        var length = obj.length,
            type = this.type(obj);
        if (this.isWindow(obj)) { return false; }
        if (obj.nodeType === 1 && length) {  return true; }
    
        return type === "array" || type !== "function" && (length === 0 || typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && (length - 1) in obj);
    }`

Comment: @Relic—that seems excessive. An "array–like" object need only have a *length* property that is a non–negative integer Number, so `isArrayLike = typeof obj.length == 'number' && /^[0-9]+$/.test(obj.length)` seems sufficient. And in any case, iteration using a standard *for* loop from `0` to `obj.length` is almost always suitable, predictable and error free (though utterly boring of course).

Comment: @Relic—also, your *isArrayLike* doesn't test that *length* is an integer, nor should it be required that there is a member at `length - 1`. It seems unreasonable to expect there to be a member there when there is no test for any other member, e.g. `{length:2.5,'1.5':'bar'}` and `{length:30,'29':'bar'}` return true.

Comment: Yea, that's capable of being as associative array or 'arrayLike'. So... that's exactly what I want... it's def not unreasonable lol... I'd want those to return true.Plus like I said... the jQuery team came up with that one.

Comment: Note that `Array.apply(null, { length: [a pretty large number] })` will result in a Range Error (*Maximum call stack size exceeded*)

Comment: @KooiInc That's true for any such use of `apply`, e.g. `Function.apply(null, { length : ... })`. You're trying to push a lot of arguments on the stack, stack isn't big enough, `RangeError`. Props to @copy for helping me figure it out.

Comment: One correction: `this` only defaults to `Window` in non-strict mode.

Comment: also `Array.from(new Array(5)).map(fn)` seems to do the same

Answer (score 21):

**Disclaimer**: This is a very formal description of the above code - this is how *I* know how to explain it. For a simpler answer - check Zirak's great answer above. This is a more in depth specification in your face and less "aha".

---

Several things are happening here. Let's break it up a bit.

```
var arr = Array.apply(null, { length: 5 }); // Create an array of 5 `undefined` values

arr.map(Number.call, Number); // Calculate and return a number based on the index passed
```

In the first line, [the array constructor is called as a function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.1) with [`Function.prototype.apply`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3).

- The `this` value is `null` which does not matter for the Array constructor (`this` is the same `this` as in the context according to 15.3.4.3.2.a.
- Then `new Array` is called being passed an object with a `length` property - that causes that object to be an array like for all it matters to `.apply` because of the following clause in `.apply`:

  - Let len be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of argArray with argument "length".
- As such, `.apply` is passing arguments from 0 to `.length` , since calling `[[Get]]` on `{ length: 5 }` with the values 0 to 4 yields `undefined` the array constructor is called with five arguments whose value is `undefined` (getting an undeclared property of an object).
- The array constructor [is called with 0, 2 or more arguments](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.2.1).
  The length property of the newly constructed array is set to the number of arguments according to the specification and the values to the same values.
- Thus `var arr = Array.apply(null, { length: 5 });` creates a list of five undefined values.

**Note**: Notice the difference here between `Array.apply(0,{length: 5})` and `Array(5)`, the first creating five times the primitive value type `undefined` and the latter creating an empty array of length 5. Specifically, [because of `.map`'s behavior (8.b)](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19) and specifically `[[HasProperty]` .

So the code above in a compliant specification is the same as:

```
var arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
arr.map(Number.call, Number); // Calculate and return a number based on the index passed
```

Now off to the second part.

- [`Array.prototype.map`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19) calls the callback function (in this case `Number.call`) on each element of the array and uses the specified `this` value (in this case setting the `this` value to `Number).
- The second parameter of the callback in map (in this case `Number.call`) is the index, and the first is the this value.
- This means that `Number` is called with `this` as `undefined` (the array value) and the index as the parameter. So it's basically the same as mapping each `undefined` to its array index (since calling [`Number`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1) performs type conversion, in this case from number to number not changing the index).

Thus, the code above takes the five undefined values and maps each to its index in the array.

Which is why we get the result to our code.

Comment: For docs: Specification for how map works: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19, Mozilla has a sample script that functions according to that specification at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility

Comment: But why does it only work with `Array.apply(null, { length: 2 })` and not `Array.apply(null, [2])` which would also call the `Array` constructor passing `2` as the length value? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyCkU/)

Comment: @Andreas `Array.apply(null,[2])` is like `Array(2)` which creates an _empty_ array of length 2 and _not_ an array containing the primitive value `undefined` two times. See my most recent edit in the note after the first part, let me know if it's clear enough and if not I'll clarify on that.

Comment: I haven't understood the way it works on the first run... After the second reading it makes sense. `{length: 2}` fakes an array with two elements which the `Array` constructor would insert into the newly created array. As there is no real array accessing the not present elements yields `undefined` which is then inserted. Nice trick :)

Answer (score 6):

As you said, the first part:

```
var arr = Array.apply(null, { length: 5 });
```

creates an array of 5 `undefined` values.

The second part is calling the `map` function of the array which takes 2 arguments and returns a new array of the same size.

The first argument which `map` takes is actually a function to apply on each element in the array, it is expected to be a function which takes 3 arguments and returns a value.
For example:

```
function foo(a,b,c){
    ...
    return ...
}
```

if we pass the function foo as the first argument it will be called for each element with

- a as the value of the current iterated element
- b as the index of the current iterated element
- c as the whole original array

The second argument which `map` takes is being passed to the function which you pass as the first argument. But it would not be a, b, nor c in case of `foo`, it would be `this`.

Two examples:

```
function bar(a,b,c){
    return this
}
var arr2 = [3,4,5]
var newArr2 = arr2.map(bar, 9);
//newArr2 is equal to [9,9,9]

function baz(a,b,c){
    return b
}
var newArr3 = arr2.map(baz,9);
//newArr3 is equal to [0,1,2]
```

and another one just to make it clearer:

```
function qux(a,b,c){
    return a
}
var newArr4 = arr2.map(qux,9);
//newArr4 is equal to [3,4,5]
```

So what about Number.call ?

`Number.call` is a function that takes 2 arguments, and tries to parse the second argument to a number (I'm not sure what it does with the first argument).

Since the second argument that `map` is passing is the index, the value that will be placed in the new array at that index is equal to the index. Just like the function `baz` in the example above. `Number.call` will try to parse the index - it will naturally return the same value.

The second argument you passed to the `map` function in your code doesn't actually have an effect on the result. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: `Number.call` is no special function that parses arguments to numbers. It is just `=== Function.prototype.call`. Only the second argument, the function that gets passed as the `this`-value to `call`, is relevant - `.map(eval.call, Number)`, `.map(String.call, Number)` and `.map(Function.prototype.call, Number)` are all equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

An array is simply an object comprising the 'length' field and some methods (e.g. push). So arr in `var arr = { length: 5}` is basically the same as an array where the fields 0..4 have the default value which is undefined (i.e. `arr[0] === undefined` yields true).
As for the second part, map, as the name implies, maps from one array to a new one. It does so by traversing through the original array and invoking the mapping-function on each item.

All that's left is to convince you that the result of mapping-function is the index. The trick is to use the method named 'call'(*) which invokes a function with the small exception that the first param is set to be the 'this' context, and the second becomes the first param (and so on). Coincidentally, when the mapping-function is invoked, the second param is the index.

Last but not least, the method which is invoked is the Number "Class", and as we know in JS, a "Class" is simply a function, and this one (Number) expects the first param to be the value.

(*) found in Function's prototype (and Number is a function).

MASHAL

Comment: There's a huge difference between `[undefined, undefined, undefined, …]` and `new Array(n)` or `{length: n}` - the latter ones are *sparse*, i.e. they have no elements. This is very relevant for `map`, and that's why the odd `Array.apply` was used.