# javascript Array map with apply

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to declare and initialize an array with 0, in javascript. I created an array and set the length like this.

```
var previousRow = [];
previousRow.length = 5;
```

Then, I did this.

```
console.log(previousRow);
previousRow = previousRow.map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
console.log(previousRow);
```

and I got,

```
[ , , , ,  ]
[ , , , ,  ]
```

But, when I did

```
console.log(previousRow);
previousRow = Array.apply(null, previousRow).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
console.log(previousRow);
```

I got what I expected

```
[ , , , ,  ]
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Why the first code didn't work?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18947892/617762

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the MDN documentation for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It clearly states:

> `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

The `previousRow` array is an empty array of `length` `5`. However the elements have never been assigned a value:

```
var previousRow = [];
previousRow.length = 5;
```

Since the elements of `previousRow` have never been assigned a value they will never be processed by `map`. Hence mapping `Number.prototype.valueOf` over `previousRow` will result in an empty array of 5 elements:

```
console.log(previousRow);
previousRow = previousRow.map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
console.log(previousRow);
```

However when you `apply` `previousRow` to the `Array` constructor the constructor creates a new array and assigns the values of `previousRow` to the new array.

It doesn't matter whether the elements of `previousRow` were assigned a value. When JavaScript can't find a value it supplies `undefined` instead.

Hence the net effect is that the new array has 5 elements all of which are **assigned** `undefined` explicitly by the `Array` constructor. Hence you can use `map` to process the entire array:

```
console.log(previousRow);
previousRow = Array.apply(null, previousRow).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
console.log(previousRow);
```

You should read the following answer for a more in depth explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/783743