# How to check if a function is called using call/apply

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(){
    console.log('foo', this);
}

foo();
foo.call({ bar: 1 });
foo.apply([{ bar: 1 }]);
```

Is there any way to know if `foo()` was called using a normal invoke or `call/apply`?

http://jsfiddle.net/H4Awm/1/

Comment: I'd say you mean `foo.call(this, { bar: 1 }));` and `foo.apply(this, [{ bar: 1 }]));` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't detect if a function is called from `call/apply` or normally.

They're not magical beings, all they do is set the arguments and `this` value. There is a [subtle difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947892/creating-range-in-javascript-strange-syntax) when it comes to undefined/undeclared values but that's it.

All [`.apply`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3) and [`.call`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4) do in ES5 is:

> Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of func, providing thisArg as the this value and argList as the list of arguments.

It sets the internal `caller` attribute correctly so something naive like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xgRfx/) would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you redefine `Function.prototype.call` and `Function.prototype.apply` (and pass another argument to your function), there is no way of doing so - the actual internal mechanics (the `[[Call]]` internal function) do not provide any method of signalling that it is called using `()`.

Compare the specification for a [general function call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) and for [`Function.prototype.apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) - each call the internal code of the function in exactly the same manner, and there is no external property set that is able to give you whether is called using that or not.

See the specification for the internal function `[[Call]]`:

> 13.2.1 `[[Call]]`
>
> When the `[[Call]]` internal method for a Function object F is called with a this value and a list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let funcCtx be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of F's [[FormalParameters]] internal property, the passed arguments List args, and the this value as described in 10.4.3.
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the FunctionBody that is the value of F's [[Code]] internal property. If F does not have a [[Code]] internal property or if its value is an empty FunctionBody, then result is (normal, undefined, empty).
> 3. Exit the execution context funcCtx, restoring the previous execution context.
> 4. If result.type is throw then throw result.value.
> 5. If result.type is return then return result.value.
> 6. Otherwise result.type must be normal. Return undefined.

There is no provision to change the running of a function from whether it is called using `call`/`apply` or not - the only thing that changes what it does are the arguments for the function itself and what is `this` meant to be within the function.

Comment: `Unless you hijack Function.prototype.call` - I'd love to see this sort of thing implemented - I believe it will prove more difficult than you'd expect since `.call` is used internally too.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I just mean redefining the function as a wrapper, I should make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solve your problem:

```
function foo(){
    console.log('foo', this);

    if (typeof this.length === "number") {
        //function has been apply
    } else {
        //function has been call
    }
}

foo();
foo.call({ bar: 1 });
foo.apply([{ bar: 1 }]);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you're passing an array for `apply`, and a object for `call`. What happens when you pass an object for both?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function foo(){

    console.log('foo', this);
    console.log( arguments );
}
Function.prototype._apply =  Function.prototype.apply;
Function.prototype.apply = function(ths,args){
    args.unshift('apply');
    this._apply(ths,args);
};

foo();
foo.call(this, { bar: 1 });
foo.apply(this, [{ bar: 1 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dirty, dirty hack:**

```
function foo() {
    var isNatural = !/foo\.(call|apply)/.test("" + foo.caller)
    console.log(isNatural ? "foo()" : "foo.{call,apply}()")
}

function caller1() {
    foo()
}
function caller2() {
    foo.call(null, { bar: 1 })
}
function caller3() {
    foo.apply(null, [{ bar: 1 }])
}

caller1()
caller2()
caller3()
```

It's just food for thought. Don't use it on production.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of a reason you should be checking for this but, you could check by comparing `this === window`, as that's the default scope (assuming browser based Javascript), but this could be faked by simply calling foo like so `foo.call(window)` which is basically what calling `foo()` is doing normally.

This also probably won't work using `window` for functions that are properties of other objects or prototypes.