# Creating array of empty strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Is there an easy way to create an array of empty strings in javascript?  Currently the only way I can think to do it is with a loop:

```
var empty = new Array(someLength);
for(var i=0;i<empty.length;i++){
    empty[i] = '';
}
```

but I'm wondering if there is some way to do this in one line using either regular javascript or coffeescript.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Update: on newer browsers - use `.fill`: `Array(1000).fill('')` will create an array of 1000 empty strings.

---

Yes, there is a way:

```
 var n = 1000;
 Array(n).join(".").split("."); // now contains n empty strings.
```

I'd probably use the loop though, it conveys intent clearer.

```
function repeat(num,whatTo){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
        arr.push(whatTo);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

That way, it's perfectly clear what's being done and you can reuse it.

Comment: +1 for cleverness and for mentioning that using the loop makes the intent clear.

Comment: This is a cool idea :-) That second function looks familiar ;-)

Comment: *(Quietly waits for someone to pick up on the by one index offset)*

Comment: I think you meant `Array(n).join('.').split('.')` also :)

Comment: `split('.')` fixed the off-by-one error with the original `split('')`

Comment: This created a very nice array of empty strings for me, but still not getting the push values recognized. 
`// Initialize empty array of strings
            let faceIds = Array(faces.length).join(".").split(".")
            for (let face of faces) {
                faceIds.push(face.faceId)
                console.log(face.faceId)
            }
            return facesIds;` It crashes and says `faceIds` are undefined.

Answer (score 27):

You can get an array defining the size and fill it with some tokens:

```js
const arr = Array(size).fill("");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What does this answer add that wasn't already better expressed in the accepted answer?

Comment: @Mogsdad The intent is way clearer and it's more readable. Best answer IMHO.

Comment: PS: This returns `any[]` not `string[]`

Answer (score 15):

here's a simpler way using generic protos on Array and String:

```
"".split.call(Array(1001), ",")
```

EDIT: There's now even simpler ways, some of which are readable:

```
Array(1000).fill("");

" ".repeat(999).split(" ");
```

Comment: (Produces 1001 empty strings.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do it by this way:

```
let n = 1000;
var emptyStrings = [...Array(n)].map(() => '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Array.from`;

```js
const n = 5;
const arr = Array.from({length: n}).map(el => "")
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This is the shortest answer I was looking for. Thanks @Sahin.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* make a function out of it:

```
function stringArray(length) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < length; ++i) { arr.push(''); }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var someLength = 10;
var empty = Array.apply(0, Array(someLength)).map(function(){return '';});
// result: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: In case anyone wonders how it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947892/creating-range-in-javascript-strange-syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
var empty = Array.apply(null, new Array(someLength)).map(String.prototype.valueOf,"");
```

Comment: +1 for clever trick with `valueOf`. Side note - new is redundant here.

Comment: A bit shorter: `String(Array([length])).split(',').map(String.prototype.valueOf,'')`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do in CoffeeScript is to use a [loop comprehension](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
a = ('' for i in [0 ... someLength]) # Note: 3 dots
a = ('' for i in [1  .. someLength]) # Or 2 dots and start at 1
#...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b9Vj9/

Comment: Save three chars with some golfing ;-) `[1..5].map(-> '')`

Answer (score 0):

Although not widely available, once browsers start supporting EcmaScript 6 array comprehensions, you will be able to do something along the lines of:

```
var n = 1000;
var empty_strs = ['' for (x of new Array(n))]
```

Comment: These are no longer part of ECMAScript 6. (Considered for ES7)

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough.

1. Array with a length of 10 items, filled with empty strings (`""`):

   ```js
   Array.from({length: 10}).map( _ => "" );
   // Array(10) [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ]
   ```
2. Array with a length of 10 items, filled with numbers from 0 to 9:

   ```js
   Array.from({length: 10}).map( (_, index) => index );
   // Array(10) [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
   ```
3. Array with a length of 10 items, filled with numbers from 1 to 10:

   ```js
   Array.from({length: 10}).map( (_, index) => index + 1 );
   // Array(10) [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
   ```
4. Array with a length of 10 items, filled with string containing `"Chapter (1 ... 10)."`:

   ```js
   Array.from({length: 10}).map( (_, index) => `Chapter ${index + 1}.` );
   // Array(10) [ "Chapter 1.", "Chapter 2.", "Chapter 3.", ... ]
   ```

(Using _ here as we don't use the value anyway.)