# Javascript: Explode a number into sequence, in order

Tags: javascript

I have a number for example 10. I want to explode it sequentially in order from 1 until 10, e.g 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

`javascript
var number = 10
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] // How to convert the number into this?`

Comment: Do you want it to be a string, or an array of values? Have you tried anything (maybe with a `for` loop)?

Comment: I tried this `$.map($(Array(10)),function(val, i) { return i; })` but it starts from 0.

Comment: You could add 1 to the result… or remove the first element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
console.log(Array.apply(null, {length:11}).map(Number.call, Number).slice(1));
```

**Output**

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Original idea from [Creating range in JavaScript - strange syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947892/1903116) and it has an awesome explanation of how this answer really works. Its a must read.

Comment: this is outside of my range :) I posted below, but this seems nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets do a quite pseudo code here and you can try it like this:

Create Array [size], consider the size to be the number entered like 10 for example;

Create a loop FOR or WHILE

- Inside do following remainder = number (10) - 1
- Array [i] = remainder

Until number (10) reaches 0... I'm sure you can do this by your self.

Comment: Great pseudo! I love the way you explain. Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome rolodex :)