# Create an array with all numbers from min to max without a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, functional-programming

I have two numbers, `min` and `max`, and I want to create an array that contains all number between them (including `min` and `max`).

The most obvious approach is to use a `for` loop for this, and `push` the single values onto an array. Nevertheless, this seems to be a quite naive approach, i.e. it's imperative programming.

Now I was thinking of how to create such an array in a more functional style. Basically, something such as the reverse of a `reduce` function: Instead of reducing an array to a number, building up an array from two numbers.

How could I do this? What is a functional approach to solve this problem?

Basically, I'm thinking of something such as `10..20` in some other languages. What's the most elegant equivalent for this in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you asking for an elegant or for a functional way?

Comment: Both ;-). It should be functional (from a technical point of view), but well readable as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of a "functional" definition of range:

```
range(low, hi) = [], if low > hi
range(low, hi) = [low] (+) range(low+1,hi), otherwise,
```

which leads to the JS definition:

```
function range(low,hi){
  function rangeRec(low, hi, vals) {
     if(low > hi) return vals;
     vals.push(low);
     return rangeRec(low+1,hi,vals);
  }
  return rangeRec(low,hi,[]);
}
```

Comment: I think, you can remove one more line and do `return rangeRec(low+1,hi, vals.concat(low));`

Comment: @thefourtheye: Yes, that would be much more functional (and you should move `rangeRec` outside of `range` then), but creating a new array on each iteration slows it down dramatically (`O(n²)` runtime)

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947892/1903116)

```
var min = 3, max = 10;
var x = Array.apply(null, {length: max + 1}).map(Number.call, Number).slice(min);
console.log(x);
// [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

The optimum version

```
var min = 3, max = 10;
var x = Array.apply(null, {length: max + 1 - min}).map(function(_, idx) {
    return idx + min;
});
console.log(x);
// [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Comment: This works. It's only drawback IMHO is that you first create an array with all number from `1` to `max` (which is not so very nice if you need only ten numbers which start at 1 billion ;-)). But apart from that: Nice solution :-)

Comment: It seems overly complicated. A for loop does the job as well, minus the useless complexity.

Comment: You should use `slice` instead of `splice`

Comment: @Bergi Got it. Updated. :)

Comment: @Virus721 I was asking for a version without loops ;-)

Comment: @GoloRoden Did you check the optimum version, that creates an array of required size only. So, it doesn't waste memory.

Comment: @Virus721 Its a style of programming called functional programming. Almost everything is done with functions.

Answer (score 6):

A one line way. Inspired by [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n).

`Array.from({length: max-min+1}, (_, i) => i + min);`

Initiate an array from a computed length based on max and min. Then map each index value by a function which is "index + min". The reference is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from).

Example:

```
const min = 12;
const max = 20;
const arr = Array.from({length: max-min+1}, (_, i) => i + min);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have harmony generators you can use this:

```
function* range(lorange,hirange){
  var n = lorange;
  while (n <= hirange){
    yield n++;
  }
}

rval= range(3,6);
```

Now you can :

1. Use the for-of comprehension for iterators as substitute of array

   ```
   for (i of rval)
   console.log(i);

   3
   4
   5
   6
   ```
2. Or you can use it to create an array like you want

   ```
   rarray = [];
   for (i of rval)
   rarray.push(i);
   ```

Comment: The idea is great :-)). Unfortunately, I need such an ranged array to explain what generators are about ;-).

Comment: @GoloRoden This is a good substitute for the 10..20 range interpolation. It is like the xrange in python 2.7 which returns elements only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Might be late to the party, but, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924644/es6-generate-an-array-of-numbers) (es6)

```js
const rangexy = (start, end) => Array.from({length: (end+1 - start)}, (v, k) => k + start);
```

Comment: And then, just after posting I realized @juminet posted a very similar one. Hehe

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1loc.dev/array/create-an-array-of-numbers-in-the-given-range/) is good exmaples.

```
const range = (min, max) => [...Array(max - min + 1).keys()].map((i) => i + min);
```