# ES6 - generate an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Having googled for it I found two solutions:

```js
    var data = [...Array(10).keys()];
console.log(data);
    var data1 = Array(8).fill().map((_, i) => i);
console.log(data1);
```

data1 displays [0, 1, ..., 7] however data just displays [[object Array Iterator]] how do I actually see the numbers.

I need it for some iterations over numbers (part of Euler project).

Previously I did a lot of Euler challenges in Python. Now I decided I'll revisit it and do as much as I can in JS (as much ES6 syntax as possible) to help me develop my js skills.

Comment: If I run `var data = [...Array(10).keys()];` in my browser (latest stable Chrome) I see the numbers listed out. I see `ArrayIterator` if I only do `Array(10).keys()`.

Comment: Is it something to do with codepen? http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/QKQGNo/?editors=1111

Comment: @Wasteland It has to do with Babel, which is being used at that specific code pen

Comment: It has to do with CodePen's use of Babel. I'm not sure what version they're running but if you disable the Babel preprocessor, everything will be correct. You can run this code [on the Babel website](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20data%20%3D%20%5B...Array(10).keys()%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(data)%3B) and you'll still see the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't babel required for ES6 features?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate a range within the supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-a-range-within-the-supp)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that works in codepen:

```
Array.from(Array(10).keys())
```

To be clear, `Array.from()` and `Array.keys()` require an ES6 polyfill in order to work in all browsers.

Comment:  Even better: `[...Array(10).keys()]`

Answer (score 77):

**A tour of Array.from thru practical examples**

`Array.from` also accepts a second argument which is used as a mapping function

```js
let out = Array.from(Array(10), (_,x) => x);
console.log(out);
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is nice to know because you might want to generate arrays that are sometimes more complex than just `0` thru `N`.

```js
const sq = x => x * x;
let out = Array.from(Array(10), (_,x) => sq(x));
console.log(out);
// [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Or you can make arrays out of generators, too

```js
function* range(start, end, step) {
  while (start < end) {
    yield start;
    start += step;
  }
}

let out = Array.from(range(10,20,2));

console.log(out); // [10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

`Array.from` is just massively powerful. People don't even realize its full potential yet.

```js
const ord = x => x.charCodeAt(0);
const dec2hex = x => `0${x.toString(16)}`.substr(-2);

// common noob code
{
  let input = "hello world";
  let output = input.split('').map(x => dec2hex(ord(x)));
  
  console.log(output);
  // ["68", "65", "6c", "6c", "6f", "20", "77", "6f", "72", "6c", "64"]
}

// Array.from
{
  let input = "hello world";
  let output = Array.from(input, x => dec2hex(ord(x)));
  
  console.log(output);
  // ["68", "65", "6c", "6c", "6f", "20", "77", "6f", "72", "6c", "64"]
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that "noob code"? I'd argue it's more readable.

Answer (score 38):

It seems the problem is that codepen precompiles your code using babel es2015-loose.

In that mode, your

```
[...Array(10).keys()];
```

becomes

```
[].concat(Array(10).keys());
```

And that's why you see an array containing an iterator.

With es2015 mode you would get

```
function _toConsumableArray(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return arr2;
  } else {
    return Array.from(arr);
  }
}
[].concat(_toConsumableArray(Array(10).keys()));
```

which would behave as desired.

See [②ality - Babel 6: loose mode](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel6-loose-mode.html) for more information about the modes.

Answer (score 36):

All of the other answers here create a temporary intermediate array, which isn't necessary.

```
Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i)
```

This is essentially a map function where you map from array index to whatever you'd like, for any number of elements.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant method and likely most performant as well using an object with a length property to pose as an iterable and the map fn integrated in the same "loop"

Answer (score 21):

Further refinement, produces an array with value starting from 1:

```
Array.from(Array(10).keys(), n => n + 1)
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a `range` function which takes `start`, `end`, and a `step` parameter. It returns an array starting a from `start` upto (but excluding) the `end` number with increments of size `step`.

```js
const range = (start, end, step) => {
  return Array.from(Array.from(Array(Math.ceil((end-start)/step)).keys()), x => start+ x*step);
}

console.log(range(1, 10, 1));
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

console.log(range(0, 9, 3));
//[0, 3, 6]

console.log(range(10, 30, 5));
//[10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Taking a step further, if you want a range that includes the `end` as well.

```js
const inclusiveRange = (start, end, step) => {
  return Array.from(Array.from(Array(Math.ceil((end-start+1)/step)).keys()), x => start+ x*step);
}

console.log(inclusiveRange(1, 10, 1));
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(inclusiveRange(0, 9, 3));
// [0, 3, 6, 9]

console.log(inclusiveRange(10, 30, 5));
//[10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```