# Fill empty array

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I need to iterate from 0 to 30, but I want to do this with help of `forEach`:

```
new Array(30).forEach(console.log.bind(console);
```

Of course this does not work, therefor I do:

```
new Array(30).join(',').split(',').forEach(console.log.bind(console));
```

Is there other ways to fill empty arrays?

Comment: Use for loop instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there's a simple way to create a `[0..N)` (i.e., not including `N`) range:

```
var range0toN = Object.keys(Array.apply(0,Array(N)));
```

Apparently `Object.keys` part can be dropped if you only want to get a proper array of N elements.

Still, like others said, in this particular case it's probably better to use `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

if you want all of item have same value, do this

```
var arrLength = 4
var arrVal = 0

var newArr = [...new Array(arrLength)].map(x => arrVal);
// result will be [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to iterate, then use `for` loop like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i += 1) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Actually, if you are looking for a way to create a range of numbers, then you can do

```
console.log(Array.apply(null, {length: 30}).map(Number.call, Number));
```

It will create numbers from 0 to 29. Source : [Creating range in JavaScript - strange syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18947892/1903116)

Comment: Haha =) I know about common for/white, but I prefer to work with forEach - it provide best encapsulation of code (speed is not important)

Comment: @3y3 What exactly you are trying to do? What should be the output?

Comment: @3y3 Does the updated answer, look fine to you? It is a neat hack ;-)

Comment: based on answer of @raina77ow I can propose ```console.log(Array.apply(null, new Array(30)).map(Number.call, Number));```. Length trick is also interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @3y3 Read the linked question to have a deeper understanding of how that works. I must say, its really worth reading :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a for loop. new Array is not a best practise

```
    var index,      // we use that in the for loop
        counter,    // number of elements in array
        myArray;    // the array you want to fill

    counter = 30;
    myArray = [];

    for (index = 0; index < counter; index += 1) {

        myArray[index] = [];
        /* 
        // alternative:
        myArray.push([]);
        // one-liner
        for (index = 0; index < counter; index += 1) myArray.push([]);
        */
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you insist `foreach`

```
var data = [1, 2, 3];
data.forEach(function(x) {
    console.log(x);
});
```