# Array(N) explanation

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I cannot find out why these lines (executed in node console) give different results...

```
> Array(3).map(x => '?')
[ , ,  ]
> [1,2,3].map(x => '?')
[ '?', '?', '?' ]
```

What does the syntax **Array(3)** means ?

Comment: MDN points out if it's an integer only passed in in the argument, it creates an array with that many items (up to that length): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax

Comment: while the explanation about *unassigned indexes* seems satisfactory, here is some further weirdness: `> x = Array(3)
[ , ,  ]
> x[2]=8
8
> x
[ , , 8 ]
` I would expect `x` having length 4, not 3

Comment: I'm guessing since it was initialized, you would have to modify the length or use `.push()` or something to add indices.

Comment: of course... [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949651/874024) explains it all