# How to convert a JavaScript Typed Array into a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript `Float32Array`, and I would like to convert it into a regular JavaScript `Array`. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need it to be an Array?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer works for all of the Javascript Typed Arrays, eg Int8Array, Float64Array, etc.  Question title could be changed to reflect this, so it's more helpful for people searching for this answer.

Comment: I submitted a change proposal to the topic and question formulation.

Comment: One use case for this would be when you want to modify typed arrays with dat.GUI

Answer (score 65):

If you don't need to support old browsers (including IE, unfortunately), you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which was [added to ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.from):

```
var array = Array.from(floatarr);
```

This [now works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) in the new releases of every browser (except IE), and it works on all major mobile browsers too.

Comment: Agreed. One can also use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in an array literal to achieve the same result. Like: `[...new Float32Array(16)]`.

Answer (score 46):

Use `Array.prototype.slice` to convert `Float32Array` to `Array`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTJDy/)

```
var floatarr = new Float32Array(12);
var array =  Array.prototype.slice.call(floatarr);
```

Comment: Join seems to work too, nice trick ! Array.prototype.join.call( floatarr, ',')

Comment: Wouldn't this easily exceed the stack size on large arrays?

Comment: @JohnWeisz No, `floatarr` is passed as `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as any array, which means you can do this :

```
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<myFloat32array.length; i++) arr[i] = myFloat32array[i];
```

But it's usually more efficient to use it as a Float32Array instead of converting it.

If you don't want to mix different types of values, don't convert it.

Answer (score 0):

In one shot:

Object.prototype.toArray=Array.prototype.slice;

Then you can use it this way:

```js
fa32 = new Float32Array([1.0010000467300415, 1.0019999742507935, 2.003000020980835]);
fa64 = new Float64Array([1.0010000467300415, 1.0019999742507935, 2.003000020980835]);

Object.prototype.toArray = Array.prototype.slice

console.log("fa32", fa32.toArray());
console.log("fa64", fa64.toArray());
```