# Take a number and turn it into an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering if there was an easier / cleaner way to expand one integer `6` and make it into an array of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

This is what I've got and I hate it.

```
var pages = function(number_int){
    var numbers_array = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= number_int; i++) {
        numbers_array.push(i);
    }
    return numbers_array;
};
```

I'd love to use underscore if I can.

Comment: This is really a question for [codereview.se], but it's so trivial I don't think it should be migrated.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but if I posted it to code review, no one would have saw it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range function in Underscore.js is pretty handy.

Here is the definition:

```
_.range([start], stop, [step])
```

- start: optional, default 0
- stop : mandatory
- step : optional, default 1

Note : range generates values in the range start(inclusive) and stop(exclusive)

So, if `number_int = 6` in your case, to generate `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` you must use the range function by specifying `stop` as `number_int + 1`

Final Answer:

```
var pages = function(number_int){
    var numbers_array = [];
    numbers_array = _.range(1,number_int + 1);
    return numbers_array;
};
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dineshchitlangia/xj8q5bea/4/

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [`range`](http://underscorejs.org/#range) function in underscore.js