# Javascript one liner range array

Tags: javascript

Is there a nice one liner for a range array in javascript, equivalent to python's `list(range(m, n))`? ES6 permitted. Here's the best I've come up with so far:

```
[x for(x of (function*(){for(let i=0;i<100;i++) yield i})())]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a JavaScript array containing 1...N](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n)

Comment: @antyrat slightly different, this one's `m..n`. Not all answers there are applicable.

Comment: Just create a function like `CreateRange(5, 10)`. Any trick one line solution I can think of is not very readable in JS.

Comment: @DavidSherret I'm indeed after readability, I could just use underscore's range otherwise.

Comment: I agree with @DavidSherret, there's no good one line. The closest would be  `Array.from({length:10-5}, (v,k) => k + 5)` but I don't find it to be terribly succint. Why does it have to be one line btw?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Array.from` and arrow functions for a better readability:

```
Array.from({length: 4}, (_, n) => n) // = [0, 1, 2, 3]
Array.from({length: 5}, (_, n) => n+6) // = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Array.from({length: 6}, (_, n) => n-3) // = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Trying any of those lines in Chrome's console produces nothing but: `eferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: @DavidThomas This is a EcmaScript 6 code. In chrome I think you need to enable it to make it work (maybe via chrome://flags ?).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
var arr = [];  while(arr[arr.length-1] !== end) arr.push(start++); // one-liner
```

Making the above to a function will result in

```
function createRange(start, end) {
   var arr = [];  while(arr[arr.length-1] !== end) arr.push(start++); // one-liner
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: you never said anything about it