# Difference between Array(n) and Array(n).fill?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've noticed that if I do:

```
Array(n).map(() => console.log('test'))
```

I get nothing printed.

However if I do:

```
Array(n).fill().map(() => console.log('test'))
```

I get `test` printed out `n` times.

Why is this the case? If I do `Array(n).length` I get back `n`.

I notice in the REPL that `Array(5)` returns:

`[ , , , ,  ]`

Whereas `Array(5).fill()` returns:

`[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

In both cases, `typeof` any element in the array `=== undefined`.

So, what's going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`map` only operates on defined integer properties of an array. `Array(n)` does not set integer properties, while `Array(n).fill()` does. There's a difference between *a property that doesn't exist* and *an extant property whose value is `undefined`*.

`Array(n)` sets the `length` property of the array, but it does not set any properties. The array object does not have any integer properties.

`.fill` sets all of the integer properties for an array from zero up to one less than `length`. When you do `Array(n)` you set the `length` property of the new aray, and then `.fill()` defines and sets each integer property up to `n-1`. The array created by `Array(n).fill()` *does* have properties defined up to `length - 1`. (The properties happen to be set to `undefined`, because you didn't pass an argument to `fill`, but they do exist.)

In pracitcal terms, you can see the difference if you do `Object.keys(Array(4))` (empty array) versus `Object.keys(Array(4).fill())` (a list of strings `"0"` to `"3"`). In the first case, the properties don't exist; in the second case they do.

Answer (score 6):

`Array(n)` creates a new array of size n, the contents have not been defined.

`Array(n).fill()` creates an array of size n where every element is set to whatever you passed into fill or undefined in your case since you passed nothing.

`Array(n).fill('test')`  creates an array of size n filled with 'test'.

Answer (score 2):

I had a requirement to create a scale using a minValue, maxValue, and precision. So, for example, with minValue = 5, maxValue = 7, and precision = 0.5, I should get the array [5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7]. I used the following (based off of answers above):

```
const tickCount = ((maxValue - minValue) / precision) + 1
const ticks = Array(tickCount)
  .fill()
  .map((x, i) => minValue + i * precision)
```