# Javascript: how to check if all three variables are different?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm doing a website project for college and I want to display three pictures on website. There are 10 pictures stored in my folder (all named "slika 1 to 10" and the script has three variables, all of them randomly generate a number between 1 and 10 and then shows a picture "slika"+randomNumber.

How can I check if all three variables are different so that those three pictures are always different whenever I  refresh the website.

JS code:

```
window.onload=odaberiSliku;

var broj1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;
var broj2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;
var broj3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;

    function odaberiSliku() {
        document.getElementById("slika1").src = "slike/randomslike/slika"+broj1+".jpg";
        document.getElementById("slika2").src = "slike/randomslike/slika"+broj2+".jpg";
        document.getElementById("slika3").src = "slike/randomslike/slika"+broj3+".jpg";
    }
```

In case anyone wonders, the variable names are in croatian.

Comment: What about generating an array from 1–10, and then shuffling it randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just check it after you generated your variables:

```
while(broj2 == broj1) {
  broj2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;)
}

while(broj3 == broj2 || broj3 == broj1) {
  broj3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;)
}
```

Comment: That's odd...I used Lux's solution and it works for now..I just added those two 'while' loops after defining all three variables.

Comment: Yes, I misread.  This works perfectly fine since it's run after the variables are generated.

Answer (score 2):

While [Lux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846552/395910) is perfectly fine, it is not scalable if you are (1) generating a dynamic list of *n* length and/or (2) if the list gets really big.

There is a simpler method to achieve what you're intending to do. You're basically trying to generate random numbers that are unique—this is akin to generating a unique array of incremental numbers and shuffling them.

Instead of going through the trial-and-error method of testing each randomly generated numbers against a pre-existing list, I believe this approach will serve you better.

All you need is to:

1. [generate a simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22499885/395910), say from 1–10 (the upper limit should correspond to the number of images you have),
2. [shuffle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript),
3. take the first 3 elements in shuffled array
4. iterate through the sliced array
5. concatenate each number to a URL template
6. assign it to your element of choice

A proof-of-concept code is as follow:

```
var imageCount = 10,
    arr = new Array(imageCount).join().split(',').map(function(item, index) {
        return ++index;
    }),
    shuffle = function(a) {
        var j, x, i;
        for (i = a.length; i; i -= 1) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
            x = a[i - 1];
            a[i - 1] = a[j];
            a[j] = x;
        }
    };

// Shuffle the array
shuffle(arr);

// Get first 3 elements
var sliced = arr.slice(0, 3);

// Iterate through first 3 elements, and assign image source
for (var i = 0; i < sliced.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("slika" + i).src = "slike/randomslike/slika" + sliced[i] + ".jpg";
}
```