# Mapping Array in Javascript with sequential numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, map-function

The following code:

```
let myArray = Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(Number.call, Number);
```

Creates the following Array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I just don't understand why.  I can't find anything on the internet that explains this behavior.  Does anyone know why this works the way it does?  Perhaps a link to some documentation?

Comment: Does this make it clearer? `Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(Function.prototype.call, Number)`

Comment: Before understand the code, please understand the concept of .map function in javascript. go throught this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10})
```

creates an array of length 10 with all elements being `undefined`.

```
.map(Number.call, Number)
```

will invoke `Number.call` for each element with the arguments `(element, index, array)` and setting `this` to `Number`. The first argument to call will be taken as `this` (not relevant here), and all the other arguments are passed as they are, with the first one being the index. And Number will now convert its first argument, `index`, to a number (here: will return the index, as it is a number), and that's what map will write to its return array.

Comment: Makes so much sense, thank you very much! Also, I found this to be very helpful: [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Seems like a convoluted way of doing this. In Python this would be 'myArray = range(0,10)'

Answer (score 16):

Let's decompose the expression in two parts:

1) Let's discuss the first expression:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10})
```

In JavaScript the `Array` constructor can take a parameter to create an array of a certain length, like:

```
Array(10) // makes an array of length 10
```

This array is a sparse array (an array which contains indexes with no elements). You can imagine we generated the following array:

```
[,,,,,,,,] // Array with 10 indexes, but no elements
```

You can think of an array in JavaScript as an object that has a `length` property and numbered indexes. For example, the following is a valid representation of an array:

```
var arr = {length: 3, 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3} // this represents the array [1, 2, 3]
```

In JavaScript we call this object an "array-like object". You can iterate this object with a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]) // logs 1 .. 2 .. 3
}
```

But this object is not an instance of the `Array` constructor:

```
arr instanceof Array // false
```

Fortunately, any array-like object can be converted to an array:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call({length: 3, 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}) // [1, 2, 3]
```

All array methods are intentionally generic to allow this behavior, so you can easily loop with `forEach` for example:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call({length: 3, 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, function(x) {
  console.log(x)
})
```

Now, back to the first expression:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10})
```

Decomposing the above expression knowing about array-like objects, we can see that is equivalent to:

```
Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
```

In other words, we are creating an array of 10 elements with a value of `undefined` (notice it is not sparse anymore)

2) Going into the second expression:

```
.map(Number.call, Number);
```

The first argument is a callback function to apply to each element in the array, the second argument is the `this` value inside the callback.

Let's decompose this expression. First we can write out the callback function as an anonymous function:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function() {
  return Number.call.apply(this, arguments)
}, Number)
```

Then we realize that `Number.call` is a shorthand for `Function.prototype.call`:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function() {
  return Function.prototype.call.apply(this, arguments)
}, Number)
```

Next, we inline the `this` value:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function() {
  return Function.prototype.call.apply(Number, arguments)
})
```

And finally we decompose the application of the function:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function() {
  return Number.call(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]) // map provides 3 arguments
})
```

As you can see, the first argument, which is the element, which is `undefined` is the `this` value of the call to `Number`, which is to say we discard it. The second argument is the index, which is the value we care about, and the third argument is not needed because `Number` only takes one argument, so this one is discarded as well.

In this case the `Number` function is used as the identity function:

```
function id(x) {
  return x
}
```

It is merely a function with one parameter that returns the argument passed into it. That's all we care about. Because `index` is already a number, we get:

```
Number(index) === id(index)
```

Hope that helps further understanding.

**Edit:** To expand on the reason why `Array(10)` won't work with iteration methods such as `map` versus `Array.apply(null, {length: 10})` we have to look at the [implementation of map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (scroll to the "Polyfill" heading).

The reason is because as I pointed out before, `Array(10)` is a sparse array, it does not have any values in it, just a length. By looking at the implementation we can see what is happening:

```
// 8. Repeat, while k < len
while (k < len) {

  var kValue, mappedValue;

  // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
  //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
  // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
  //    method of O with argument Pk.
  //   This step can be combined with c
  // c. If kPresent is true, then
  if (k in O) {

    // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with argument Pk.
    kValue = O[k];
```

You can see that in `k in O` the `in` operator checks for *existence* first, and the value does not exist; it is not `undefined`, it is just not present. This is not the same as just doing property access like `O[k]` where it would give you  a value of `undefined` if the property doesn't exist.

```
var o = {}

'p' in o // false
o.p // undefined
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much - This was actually a very nice read.  I already awarded an answer.  If this answer becomes upvoted I will change the answer to this one.  Gosh, thanks for all your effort!

Comment: Good read but it is not explaining the tricky point. The second part is just nothing but deception. It can simply be done like `.map((e,i) => i)` However the interesting part is how map woks on an array full of undefined items. Normally `Array(10).map((e,i) => i)` will not work. But in this case apparently the array obtained from `Array.apply(null, {length: 10})` is not the same as the one obtained from `Array(10)` and map works on undefined items. How is this possible..?

Comment: @Redu because `Array(10)` gives you a sparse array (and map doesn't work with it) but `Array.apply(null, {length:10})` returns array of undefined value (and map works with it)

Comment: if the second argument is the index, why do you need Number.call() for this purpose, can't you just write >> Array.apply(null, {length:10}).map( (a,i)=> i)

Comment: Excellent explanation. It was very well written and useful to read. Thank You!

Answer (score 6):

es6 simpliedfied version

```js
let k = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((currentElement, i) => i)

console.log(k)

// Output -[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 10})
```

//> it outputs the array of undefined, with the length of ten, why:
it takes null for execution because it does not need this for execution, besides this argument must be tepeof object, and as we know: typeof null === 'object', if you will place any other object instead of null, it will do the same thing, it matters only what is the length of the second argument( it tests the length of the second argument),

.map(Number.call, Number);

decompose(we know that Number constructor is Function.prototype(Number.**proto**), so):

```
.map(function(){
Function.prototype.call.apply(this, arguments)
}, Number)// the second arg is the this value that map function takes during each iteration
```

We also know that this is Number, cause every time it calls Number as this:

```
Function.prototype.call.apply(Number, arguments)
```

});//here we don't need second argument

Now we compose everything again:
Function.prototype => Number,

```
call.apply(Number, arguments); => call(arguments[0], arguments[1])
```

reason: arguments is array-like object, we can still pass it to apply method, but we cannot to call, cause it takes arguments separated by comma.You cannot define arguments as an argument, so you need to indicate what it is looking for: index, and that is arguments[1], as this value it must take any object, so it take: null, or anything, but it must be present:

```
return Number.call(null, arguments[1]);
```

Here Number is an identity function:

```
function example(x){
 return x;
}
```

so Number(e) == example(e);
so on first iteration:

```
Number(0) //it takes 0 index:

return 0..
```

then:

```
Number(1)//cause it takes the index of the second element:

return 1..
```

Thanks for reading...