# Why using `Number.prototype.valueOf` inside of a `map()` without optional arg gives an error

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888562/why-do-we-use-number-prototype-valueof-inside-of-a-map-function) I tried to perform a modification to the code that creates an array filled with zeroes:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
```

Instead of this, I wanted to use `fill` and understand in a better way the usage of the `map` function in Javascript. Using the developer tools in Chrome I executed the following, getting an error:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10)).fill(0).map(Number.prototype.valueOf);

Uncaught TypeError: Number.prototype.valueOf is not generic
```

As I understand the map function, it executes the callback on each value of the array using that value as argument. The array is correctly created using `Array.apply(null, Array(10)).fill(0)`, so it should be executing `Number.prototype.valueOf(0)`, why is it giving then the error?

Comment: You have to pass it value... valueOf,[number]

Comment: If I use it without argument, shouldn't it be using already the values of the prefilled array?

Comment: You already have an "Array filled with zeroes". Why the call to `map(Number.prototype.valueOf)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it should be executing `Number.prototype.valueOf(0)`, why is it giving then the error?

No. The `map` callback is called with no (`undefined`) `this` argument if you don't pass one to `map`, and the array element, the index, and the array as arguments. So it actually calls

```
Number.prototype.valueOf.call(undefined, 0, 0, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

But `valueOf` must be invoked on numbers or `Number` instances, otherwise it will throw.

Comment: Ok, I see that Number.prototype.valueOf is not a function that you use with a parameter but as an instance function of the Number class to retrieve the primitive value. Using `Array.apply(null, Array(10)).fill(0).map(a => a.valueOf());` performs as expected. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN, the `map` method accepts two parameters, the second one is `Value to use as this when executing callback`. So when you call:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
```

You actually call `Number.prototype.valueOf.call(0)` which always return 0.
As you know, if `map` accept a function that is always return 0, it creates an array filled with 0.

And if you remove the second parameter as below:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf);
```

It throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Number.prototype.valueOf is not generic(...)
```

You may figure out what the default `this` is for `map` in your environment:

```
[0].map(v=>{console.log(this);}) // =>Window for chrome developer tools
```

So try this:

```
Number.prototype.valueOf.call(window)
```

You may get the same error info.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for `map` is used as `this`. In the first case, `this` each time is the number `0` (which is converted to an object `Number(0)`)

Consequently, the `map` function is calling `Number.prototype.valueOf` with `this` being `Number(0)`. This is effectively the same as `Number(0).valueOf()` , which is naturally the number `0`.

(NOT `Number.prototype.valueOf(0)` - try calling `Number.prototype.valueOf(1)` and see what that gets you)

Meanwhile, if you don't pass the `this` argument to `map()`, then it is set to `window`. This means you're effectively calling `Number.prototype.valueOf` on the `window`. That makes no sense, and so an error is thrown. It doesn't matter that `0` is the argument, because `Number.prototype.valueOf()` *takes no arguments*. `Number(0).valueOf(1)` returns `0` because the argument is ignored completely.

Comment: "*(which is converted to an object `Number(0)`)*" - if you mean `new Number(0)`, then actually no. `this` is not cast to an object in builtin methods. It also is never set to `window`, where would that come from?

Comment: @Bergi That's what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) says...

Comment: And as so often these days, MDN is wrong :-/ I've rolled back [this edit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map$compare?to=1003361&from=979867). It's always just sloppy mode that lets `this` values in callback functions default to the global object when nothing is passed.

Comment: Ah, I see... Fair enough then.