# how do you render GoogleMaps API to a route-specific HTML Div element?

Tags: google-maps, meteor, reactjs

I'm using React  Meteor 1.3 and this google maps package.
https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps-react-example.

I can successfully render the map to a single page App, however as soon as I add routing to the mix - things stop working. Specifically when I move the  element from an index html template to a JSX component that renders to the page - it breaks. I'm at a bit of a loss here and as the problem is quite vague (in my mind at least) I can't find an answer on google.

What's happening here? Does anyone have an example of this package working with flowrouter?

My current working set up looks like this.

Map.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

MyTestMap = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  componentDidMount() {
    GoogleMaps.load();
  },
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      loaded: GoogleMaps.loaded(),
      mapOptions: GoogleMaps.loaded() && this._mapOptions()
    };
  },
  _mapOptions() {
    return {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
      zoom: 8
    };
  },
  render() {
    if (this.data.loaded)
      return <GoogleMap name="mymap" options={this.data.mapOptions} />;

    return <div>Loading map...</div>;
  }
});

GoogleMap = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    options: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    GoogleMaps.create({
      name: this.props.name,
      element: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this),
      options: this.props.options
    });

    GoogleMaps.ready(this.props.name, function(map) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.options.center,
        map: map.instance
      });
    });
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (GoogleMaps.maps[this.props.name]) {
      google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(GoogleMaps.maps[this.props.name].instance);
      delete GoogleMaps.maps[this.props.name];
    }
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div  id="mapId" className="map-container"></div>
)
  }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    return ReactDOM.render(<MyTestMap />, document.getElementById('root'));
  });
}
```

And then I render this to an Index.html file - however this means that the map is on every page.

```
<head>
  <title>googlemaps-react</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly post a github link to your project?  Maybe paste code up in here to show what you're working with.  Without doing so, I fear you risk getting this question down-voted by the stackOverflow *"nay sayers"*.  Without seeing some code I won't be able to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yah, no worries. [I'm sure you have read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but if in case you haven't - it's a good read.  [I was doing it wrong until I figure this out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37887038/484732).  It's better to ask short and simple questions, as if you're speaking to a child on StackOverflow - or people get pissy.  Other sites are more conversational and your questions would be perfectly formatted there.  Sometimes adding code and such is not enough, literally HOW you ask a question effects the response you get from this site greatly.