# Using array.prototype.fill instead of array.prototype.push

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use the following prototype to `fill` an empty array with integers from 1-100. As per MDN's documentation:

`array.prototype.fill(value, [optional start & end index])`

If my understanding is correct if I call my `value = 1` then if I say:

`[5].fill(1);` I would be left with an array with 1 sitting at all 5 index points of the array. Is there a way using `.fill()` to say `value = 1...100`? I'm beginning to think running a for loop to `push` values 1 - 100 might be the only way to do this, but I thought I would see if this method worked the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method, doesn't take a function or an iterator as an argument to change the static value with every iteration.

try this approach

```js
    var N = 100;
    var arr = Array.apply(null, {length: N+1}).map(Number.call, Number);
    arr.splice(0,1); 

console.log(arr);
```

`splice` at the end removes the first item of the array which was `0`.

If you don't want to do `splice`

```js
        var N = 100;
        var arr = Array.apply(null, {length:  N}).map(Number.call, function(item, index){ return item + 1 });

    console.log(arr);
```

Some other good approaches are mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n) to fill values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

> The fill() method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a **static** value.

Therefore, it will not be possible to increment this value using the `fill()` method.