# A non-repeating pseudo random number generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate 6-digit numeric coupon codes in JavaScript.

I'd like to use something like [Preshing's algorithm](http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/).

This is what I have so far,

```
const p = 1000003;

function permuteQPR(x) {
  const residue = x * x % p;
  return (x <= p/2) ? residue : p - residue;
}

function next() {
  return permuteQPR(
    (permuteQPR(m_index++) + m_intermediateOffset) ^ 0x5bf03635
  );
};

const seedBase = 123456;
const seedOffset = 44;
m_index = permuteQPR(permuteQPR(seedBase) + 0x682f0161);
m_intermediateOffset = permuteQPR(
  permuteQPR(seedOffset) + 0x46790905
);

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += ('000000' + next()).substr(-6) + "<br>";
}
```

There is also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d10z9u7m/).

Comment: Convert it to JavaScript yourself? Although in reality, all you need to do is shuffle an ordered array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript.

Comment: Your all very helpful..  To me this seems a valid question, and it's certainly not asking the same question as shuffling an array.  The link the OP posted was for generating unique random numbers without the overhead of an Array.

Comment: @obiwahn,.. I've just done a quick convert of the source code from your link, and it appears to work fine.  Tested by creating 10 million random numbers, and checking there is no duplicate.  If this question gets taken of hold I could post here.

Comment: @Keith You could also post a link to a jsfiddle in a comment here

Comment: Sorry guys. Could someone please explain to me why this is on hold? I am rather new to JavaScript and I asked this question because I am not able to convert it by myself. Plus I think this would be really useful for many other members of this community.

Comment: @obiwahn It was put on hold (I presume) because the original wording sounded like you were looking for someone to point you to an off-site resource. I re-worded your question to ask specifically for help rewriting the algorithm in JS and then flagged it for reopen.

Answer (score 0):

This one works and is unique:

```
const p = 1000003;
const seed1 = 123456;
const seed2 = 123457;


function calculateResidue(x) {
    const residue = x * x % p;
  return (x <= p/2) ? residue : p - residue;
}


function valueForIndex(index) {
        const first = calculateResidue((index + seed1) % p);
        return result = calculateResidue((first + seed2) % p);
};

let codes = [];
for(i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
    const code = valueForIndex(i);
  if(codes.indexOf(code)==-1) codes.push(code);
};


document.body.innerHTML += "Unique codes: " + codes.length;
```