# Javascript Avoiding Nested For Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've noticed my algorithm solutions often include ugly nested for loops when better options are available. In the example below, how can I determine the prime numbers up to the given parameter without nested loops? One constraint of the assignment was to *not* utilize any external functions.

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
    var p = [];
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
        p.push(i);
        for (var j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j === 0) //not a prime
            {
                p.pop(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
```

Comment: Just about anywhere you use nested loops, you can use recursion. It is typically a more complicated solution to wrap your mind around, but they accomplish the same task

Comment: What do they mean by "external" functions? You can move the inner loop to its own function but define it inside `sumPrimes`. Or are they saying not to use library functions?

Comment: Would `Math.sqrt()` be allowed, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any other good solution but I came up with this. There is still one for loop ;)

```
function primes(num) {
  return Array.apply(null, {length: (num + 1)}).map(Number.call, Number)
   .filter(function(n) {
     for(var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
       if(n % i === 0) return false;
     }
     return n !== 0 && n !== 1;
   })
 }
```

Explanation:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: (num + 1)}).map(Number.call, Number)
```

This line creates an Array with the range of the passed argument. If `num` would be `5` it would create the following Array: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n).

Then I use the `filter` function to remove all non prime numbers. If the filter function returns `false` the number will be removed from the array. So inside the filter function we check if the current number is a prime number. If so, `true` is returned. As you can see I still use a normal for loop here.

No you can call the function as follows: `primes(28);`

This will return the following Array: `[ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 ]`

In this specific case I would say to use normal for loops is absolutely ok. But always consider functions like `map`, `reduce` or `filter` when you operate on arrays.

Comment: This answer is not exactly correct, `.map()` & `.filter()` are for loops but disguised on a built-in javascript method.