# Filling an array with the same object model

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'am trying to fill an array (rooms) with the same object type (room).

This works fine :

```
var rooms = new Array(10);

for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
  rooms[i] = new room();
}
```

Isn't there any other method that takes only one line of code to do the same thing?

I've tried :

```
var rooms = new Array(10).fill(new room());
```

but each box of the array contains the same object (same reference).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map` method in order to have different objects.

```
var rooms = new Array(10).fill().map(function(){
   return new room();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n) will work in (since ES6):

```
Array(10).fill().map((e,i)=>new room());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another nice way of doing this would be;

```
var rooms = Array.from({length:10}, _ => new Room());
rooms[0] === rooms[1] // <- false
```