# Best way to fill an array with start value and end value (integer)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am calling for a modal to open with a $uibModal and i want to fill an array with integers from m to n. Because the range between the numbers is very big sometimes, the modal is opening very slow. I need to show inside the select box the values of the array. Any suggestions?
this is my code:

```
vm.arr = [];

while (step > 0 ? max >= min : max <= min) {
      vm.arr.push(min);
      min += step;
}
```

Comment: If there are enough numbers to slow down the browser, it's unlikely to be a good user experience to have to select the number itself...

Comment: Agreed. If there are that many numbers in the range, maybe you could just let the user type the number and do a range check on the result?

Comment: @Mark Reed I think this is the best solution for now, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a JavaScript array containing 1...N](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n)

Comment: Also, it's unlikely the `while` loop that's causing the slow down. That's simple code that should work fine. It's more likely how you're binding it. For instance, try using `var arr = []; while (...) { arr.push(min); } vm.arr = arr;`. When you push items into a bound array, that triggers AngularJS to recreate the `select` over and over again.