# Generate an array with values that are a range of multiples of 7 using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like the most modern way to make an array like this

```
const nextchunk = [];
nextchunk[0] = [0, 6];
nextchunk[1] = [7, 13];
```

Each nextchunk must have 7 places in it as shown. These represent a limit query later in in the code. So `nextchunk[1]` gets out item 7 - 13, `nextchunk[2]` gets out 14 - 20

I would like the flexibility of being able to call `nextchunk[20]` at runtime and have it return the correct values.

Comment: Start by using a loop to generate them, then go for [`Array.from({length: 21}, (_, i) => …)` or something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3746725/1048572)

Comment: Amazing. -3 yet 3 answers from very experienced stackers - that would suggest the opposite.

Comment: You know that question downvotes mean "*This post does not show any effort*"? You can still [edit] to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   function chunks(size) {
     return function getChunk(index) {
       return [size * index, size * (index + 1) - 1];
     }
   }

   const nextchunk = chunks(7);
   console.log(
      nextchunk(0), 
      nextchunk(1), 
      nextchunk(20)
   );
```

You can easily calculate the value. There is no need to generate it before it is actually needed. If you really need the array, its easy to build it up with the upper helper:

```
  const nextchunk = Array.from({length: 21}, (_, i) => chunks(7)(i));
  console.log(nextchunk[20]);
```

Comment: …apart from when you need `nextchunk(0) == nextchunk(0)`

Comment: I guess returned function's name (`get`) is a bit excess as it is not being used anywhere.

Comment: @mohammad it improves readability and helps furing debugging.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like the flexibility of being able to call `nextchunk[20]` at
>   runtime and have it return the correct values.

Though I **don't** recommend to use this approach in production (mainly because you won't be able to transpile it to work in elder js engines) but you could achive `nextchuck[20]` syntax using [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```js
// just for fun
const nextChunk = new Proxy([], {
  get(target, prop) {
    const maybeIndex = parseInt(prop, 10)
    const has = Reflect.has(target, prop)
    const value = Reflect.get(target, prop)
    
    if (has) { 
      return value
    }
    
    if(!Number.isNaN(maybeIndex)) {
      const newValue = [maybeIndex * 7, 6 + maybeIndex * 7]
      Reflect.set(target, prop, newValue );
      
      return newValue;
    }
    
    return value;
  }
});

console.log(nextChunk[0], nextChunk[1], nextChunk[20])
console.log(nextChunk[0] === nextChunk[0])
```

Comment: Definetly the most creative approach :)

Comment: @JonasW. Used Proxies for some PoC code this week. :) Just can't stop seeing em everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could create custom function that takes array and `number` and adds new element to array based on your calculation.

```js
const arr = [];
const nextchunk = (array, chunk) => {
  const start = chunk * 6 + chunk;
  array.push([start, start + 6])
}

nextchunk(arr, 0);
nextchunk(arr, 1);
nextchunk(arr, 2);
nextchunk(arr, 20);

console.log(arr)
```