# Is there a way to create an Integer range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to create an Integer range?

In other languages, I can use `Range(1, 9)` to create `[1, 2, ... 8]` easily.

Is there a simple way to create the list in JavaScript?

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish with a range if I may ask?

Comment: See this question which has lots of different approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-integer-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const range = (start, end) => Array.from({length: end - start}, (_, i) => start + i);

 console.log(range(1,5));
```

That creates an array with the indexes. If you need it in a loop, an iterator might be better:

```
 function* range(start, end = Infinity) {
   for(let i = start; i < end; i++)
     yield i;
 }
```

Which can be used as:

```
 for(const v of range(1, 10))
    console.log(v);
```

You can also turn an iterator into an array easily:

```
 console.log([...range(0, 10)]);
```

Comment: This will give error for Range(9,1). This case is also not handled

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to create the list in JavaScript?

No, but you can create your own solution using `ES` features like `map` and `spread syntax`.

```js
var range = (start, end) => start < end ? [...Array(end - start)].map((_, i) => start + i) : [];
console.log(range(1,9));
```

Also, `returns` an `empty` array for case when `start` is greater than `end`.

Comment: OP needs 1-8 if input with `(1,9)`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, updated.

Comment: This will give error for `Range(9,1)`. This case is also not handled

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, for `start > end` I returns just an empty array.

Comment: Yes, it seems good now

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, python also returns an empty list for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reusable function called `Range` and loop over the start and end values. You can further add a `if` condition that ensures that the start value is always less than the end value.

```js
function Range(start, end){
  var rangeArray = [];
  if(start < end){
    for(var i=start; i<end; i++){
      rangeArray.push(i);
    }
  }
  return rangeArray;
};

console.log(Range(1,9));
console.log(Range(2,9));
console.log(Range(5,12));
console.log(Range(16,12));
console.log(Range(30,12));
```