# Why array created by Array(3) don't have index 0, 1, 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

`Array(3)`, result:

```
{ length: 3__proto__: Array(0) }
```

There is no `index` `0, 1, 2`...

But `Array.call(null, Array(3))` has,

```
{ 0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined, length: 3, __proto__: Array(0) }
```

I know I can get indexs by Array.from or Array.fill.

I just want to know why Array.call(null, Array(3)) can produce the indexs. I want to know the inner logic of Array.call(null, Array(3)), What does it exactly do ?

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: `Array(3).fill()` is too hard because why?

Comment: `Why Array(5) don't have index 0, 1, 2, 3?` it doesn't have index 4 either - just sayin :p - what you want to look for in documentation is *sparse array*

Comment: @31 no, it's no duplicate, I know Array and new Array is the same,  I want to know why Array()/new Array() don't have index, comparing to Array.call().

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I know Array.fill can make it. I just want to know if any other ways to create array with index without it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,You can use `Array.from` to transform the array, like this

```
Array.from(Array(3),(val,index)=>index)
// [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.length` is read and writable. Setting the internal length reference doesn't automatically create empty values. By instaniating an array `Array(5)` you're setting the internal length, but creating a blank array. If you were to push a value in its index would be 6 but the array would still only contain one item.

Run these too examples in a console. They're equivalent.

```
let a = Array(5)
a.push('foo') // length 6
a.push('bar') // length 7
a // [empty × 5, "foo", "bar"]

let b = []
b.length = 5
b.push('foo') // length 6
b.push('bar') // length 7
b // [empty × 5, "foo", "bar"]

a.forEach(i => console.log(i))
// foo
// bar
```

Using `Array.call(null, 5)` produces the same result as above. Its essentially calling `Array(5)` with a context of `null`; `Array.call(null, Array(3))` is creating a nested array, with the first value being an array set to length 3.

There is a shortish hand way described in this answer [Create a JavaScript array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n)

```
var N = 10; 
Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number)
```