# Angular Controls/ generating array from number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a number in my application value is 6,

by using this value i have to create an array of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] using javascript/typescript

i have tried this in my application

```
 this.builder.group({
          'staff': this.builder.group({
          staff: [false],
          id: [this.staffData[i].users[j].id],
          labelName: [this.staffData[i].users[j].name],
          controlname: ['staff'],
          cssclass: ['error'],
          checked: [false],
          customcss: ['test1'],
          dayid: this.selectedDay,
          number: Array(this.appointmentsData.numberofSlots).fill().map((x,i) => i)})
})
```

but i am  getting  number as 0 in browser console.
in VSCode also it is showing excepted 1-3 arguments but got 0 (i think it is for fill() method as i am passing 0 values , but i am unable to understand what to pass for fill() arguments)  please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.apply(null, {length: N}).map(Number.call, Number)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas, will try and let you know

Comment: it is throwing below error  core.js:1440 ERROR TypeError: this.validator is not a function
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.js:3433)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3387)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:3905)
    at FormBuilder.control (forms.js:7905)
    at FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:7971)
    at eval (forms.js:7947)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormBuilder._reduceControls (forms.js:7946)
    at FormBuilder.group (forms.js:7867)
    at AddStaffComponent.addStaffsGroup (add-staff.component.ts:129)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a JavaScript array containing 1…N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), where our friend Tomas found his answer : >