# JavaScript, how to create an array that sequentially counts till N?

Tags: javascript

Not sure how exactly to word this, but essentially, I'm trying to write a function that if you input 5, it will return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], if you input 7, it will return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] etc etc.

It seems simple but for some reason it's just not clicking for me.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically about this do you need help with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a JavaScript array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for-loop that pushes to an array:

```js
function count(n){
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(count(5));
console.log(count(7));
```