# Spread operator + keys() method: Add additional value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 100 items in an array, where each item contains a number (0-99) and a boolean, by achieving the result below using spread operator and the `keys()` method.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    room.push({roomId: i, isAvailable: true});
}
```

Is it possible to add a boolean along with each item that was generated with `keys()`?

```
var room = [...Array(100).keys()] // to [{ roomId: 0, isAvailable: true }, ...]
```

Comment: not without an additional map. .keys returns an iterator and ... spreads it. you'll have to add another step to map it to an object. `Array.from( Array(100), ( _, i ) => ({ roomId: i, isAvailable: true}) )` for example.

Comment: [How to create an array containing 1…N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) paired with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get your expected result.

```js
let rooms = Array(100)
    .fill()
    .map((_,roomId) => ({roomId, isAvailable: true}));

console.log(rooms);
```

With `lodash` you can use the [`_.times`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#times) util:

```js
let rooms = _.times(100, roomId => ({roomId, isAvailable: true}));
console.log(rooms);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @charlietfl you're right i totally forgot to remove the spread.

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and take the index as id.

```js
var length = 100,
    isAvailable = true,
    result = Array.from(
        { length },
        (_, roomId) => ({ roomId, isAvailable })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```