# Creating new instance without name

Tags: javascript

what is the best way to create a lot of instance? 
For example if I have class Enemy, and i want to spawn 100 units, should I create loop, and name each in turn differently, or is any easier way to do that? I'm asking about javascript. Thanks

Comment: You will find your answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n. For short, yes, there is nothing wrong to a for loop. Depends on your Enemy constructor (how you want to generate your objects)

Answer (score -1):

The best way is probably a for loop, unless you have some mega-specific stuff going on in the Enemy constructor (in which case you should expand your question because I'm interested). For what you are trying to do I would imagine it would look something like this:

```
Let firstnames = [list of 10 first names]
Let secondnames = [list of 10 second names]
class Enemy () {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
for(let i=0;i==10i++){
    for(let j=0, j==10, j++) {
        let name = firstname[i].toString+" "+secondname[j].toString
        new Enemy(name[i])
    }
}
```